# How to sort BibTeX references in reverse chronological order?

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, sorting

I am trying to get my list of publications to display in reverse chronological order.  I can use `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` as a workaround, and just order the entries manually, but I would naturally prefer if BibTeX did that for me.

What tools or approaches can I take to sort the bibliography in reverse chronological order?

Comment: If you cannot find an already-made solution, you may consider looking at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try https://github.com/plessl/latex-goodies/tree/master/bibstyles/plainyr-rev

Haven't tested it myself. Good luck.

Comment: @Raphink http://blog.plesslweb.ch/post/6628963116/bibtex-style-for-sorting-in-reverse-chronological-order  Edit: Direct link to Github: https://github.com/plessl/latex-goodies/tree/master/bibstyles/plainyr-rev

Answer (score 43):

Here's a solution using [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{a01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{b03,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{c02,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

See sections 3.1.2.1 and 3.5 of the `biblatex` documentation for details.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not take months/day into account. However as mentionned in [this github issue](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/860#issuecomment-456976656), you can either define your sorting method yourself, or use the [biblatex-publist](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-publist) style (for CVs).

Answer (score 20):

The bibliography style **plainyr** is a good starting point if you don't want to (or cannot) use biblatex.  This style is similar to **plain**, but sorts the references chronologically by year.  To get reverse chronological order, copy `plainyr.bst` to another file (such as `plainrevyr.bst`).  Edit the new file and replace every occurrence of `ITERATE` with `REVERSE` as described in the previous answer.

`plainyr.bst` is the best starting point because it is the only default style that uses date as the primary sorting field, as described in http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/perl/b4w_using.html#Sort

If you attempt to replace `ITERATE` with `REVERSE` in any other style you will change the sort order, but not the primary sort field.  For example, starting with ieeetr results in a bibliography that is *mostly* sorted in reverse chronological order...and mostly isn't good enough for your CV!

Comment: Simple yet awesome!

Comment: Works pretty well, and is easy to implement. However, there are just a few bibles entries in my bib file for which are not put in the right order. Here is one example (and I don't see, why it would fail to sort that in the correct position):   <br/>. 

    @Proceedings{Zachmann-2007-WorkshopTrends,
      editor    = "Gabriel Zachmann",
      title     = "Proc. IEEE VR 2007 Workshop on 'Trends and Issues in
                                      Tracking for Virtual Environments'",
      month     = mar,
      year      = 2007,
      address   = "Charlotte, NC, USA",
    }
.

Answer (score 12):

If you're willing to customise an existing style (any existing style which orders things in ascending date order), then take the corresponding `.bst` file, head to the bottom, and replace `ITERATE {call.type$}` with `REVERSE {call.type$}`.

Details: You can find the existing file with (on unixes) `kpsewhich plain.bst` (if you want to customize the `plain` style).  Copy that file to, say, `myplain.bst`, edit it, and then use `{myplain}` as your bibliographystyle.

**Edited** to clarify which `ITERATE` call to change.

Comment: there are many lines with `ITERATE` like `ITERATE {presort}` or `ITERATE {longest.label.pass}
`
Which one is the good one?

Comment: Good point.  I edited the answer suitably.  As Craig Finch's answer points out, to do a complete job would require adjusting the `presort` function to move the `year field.or.null sortify` line to the top of the function, but that's getting into more detailed .bst hacking.

Answer (score 6):

I did this using the macro file `makebst.tex`, which takes you through a list of Q&A options, one of which is sort order.

I then copied over relevant chunks of code from the new .bst that macro made to the style file I actually wanted to use.  The code copied:

```
FUNCTION {negate.year}
{ year empty$
    { "99999" }
    { year #1 #1 substring$ chr.to.int$ #105 swap$ - int.to.chr$
      year #2 #1 substring$ chr.to.int$ #105 swap$ - int.to.chr$ *
      year #3 #1 substring$ chr.to.int$ #105 swap$ - int.to.chr$ *
      year #4 #1 substring$ chr.to.int$ #105 swap$ - int.to.chr$ *
    }
    if$
}
```

I've now added month-based sorting (which is kind of ugly because the month three-letter abbreviations need to be parsed into #'s):

```
FUNCTION {sort.format.month}
{ 't :=
  t #1 #3 substring$ "l" change.case$ "jan" =
    { "01"  }
    { t #1 #3 substring$ "l" change.case$ "feb" =
      { "02"  }
      { t #1 #3 substring$ "l" change.case$ "mar" =
        { "03"  }
        { t #1 #3 substring$ "l" change.case$ "apr" =
          { "04"  }
          { t #1 #3 substring$ "l" change.case$ "may" =
            { "05"  }
            { t #1 #3 substring$ "l" change.case$ "jun" =
              { "06"  }
              { t #1 #3 substring$ "l" change.case$ "jul" =
                { "07"  }
                { t #1 #3 substring$ "l" change.case$ "aug" =
                  { "08"  }
                  { t #1 #3 substring$ "l" change.case$ "sep" =
                    { "09"  }
                    { t #1 #3 substring$ "l" change.case$ "oct" =
                      { "10"  }
                      { t #1 #3 substring$ "l" change.case$ "nov" =
                        { "11"  }
                        { t #1 #3 substring$ "l" change.case$ "dec" =
                          { "12"  }
                          { "00"  } % No match
                        if$
                        }
                      if$
                      }
                    if$
                    }
                  if$
                  }
                if$
                }
              if$
              }
            if$
            }
          if$
          }
        if$
        }
      if$
      }
    if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {negate.month}
{ month empty$
    { "999" }
    { 
      month sort.format.month #1 #1 substring$ chr.to.int$ #105 swap$ - int.to.chr$
      month sort.format.month #2 #1 substring$ chr.to.int$ #105 swap$ - int.to.chr$ *
    }
    if$
}
```

and `bib.sort.order` was replaced with:

```
FUNCTION {bib.sort.order}
{ sort.label
  "    "
  *
  negate.month field.or.null sortify
  swap$
  *
  negate.year field.or.null sortify
  swap$
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}
```

EDIT: Now sorts by year-then-month.  I actually understand what all the code does now, too, which is an improvement.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I've modified the style apalike-refs https://github.com/matthieu-vergne/LaTeX to include your sorting options and the result is here: https://gist.github.com/fredrike/ad0fdafcebf7fab2aef3930a3fd2a6da

Answer (score -3):

Here's another possibility:

1. Download and install [Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/).
2. Download and install [JabRef](https://www.jabref.org/).
3. Open a terminal or command window.
4. Change directory to where JabRef is installed.
5. Start JabRef: `java -jar JabRef-4.3.1.jar`
6. Click **File ➡ Open library**.
7. Browse to and select your database (e.g., `database.bib`).
8. Click **Open**.
9. Click **File ➡ Library properties**.
10. Select **Save entries ordered as specified**.
11. Set **Primary sort criterion** to: `year`
12. Check **Descending**.
13. Set **Secondary sort criterion** to: `author`.
    [image: Properties Dialog]
14. Click **OK**.
15. Click **File ➡ Save library as**.
16. Provide a new filename (e.g., `sorted-database.bib`).
17. Click **Save**.

The library is saved in the desired order.

From there, you can use the file's pre-sorted order. In ConTeXt this would resemble:

```
\def\textrm{\rm}

\usebtxdataset[mybiblio][sorted-database.bib]
\definebtxrendering[mybiblio][apa][
  dataset=mybiblio,
  numbering=yes,
  sorttype=index,
]

\starttext
  \startbackmatter
    \startchapter[title=Bibliography]
      \placelistofpublications[mybiblio][method=dataset]
    \stopchapter
  \stopbackmatter
\stoptext
```