# Multibib reverse label or sort order

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting, multibib, subdividing

I'm using [`multibib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibib). I manually set the order of the bibliography. I would like the order of the numbered items to be reversed. For example, my document has:

```
\nociteX{Foo}
\nociteX{Bar}
```

And the document then shows:

```
[1] Foo
[2] Bar
```

I would like the document to show:

```
[2] Foo
[1] Bar
```

Can anyone explain what to change in my `.bst` file, or a flag to `multibib` that I am missing that will achieve this?

Comment: It might depend on your bibstyle, but changing `ITERATE {call.type$}` to `REVERSE {call.type$}` should invert the order of the entries. However, this will also reverse the numbering of the references.

Comment: If you're willing to switch to [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21401/biblatex-reverse-numbering-i-e-count-down.

Comment: @mankoff: Have a look at the documentation. One possibility is to work with keywords.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4461/4427

Comment: @mankoff Are your references split off into separate `bib` files? If so, the question lockstep linked is relevant - you'd just add the `defernumbers=true` package option and `prefixnumbers={F}` (or `{J}` - whatever the relevant prefix is) in `\printbibliography`.

Comment: They are not split. It seems `biblatex` is the way to go, but have not yet figured out how to do what multibib does with it. I know it can be done, just haven't figured out how yet...

Comment: @mankoff A single `bib` file would need a different approach. It's possible - I just don't have time ATM to look into it.

Comment: @Audrey: I'd really like to see a `biblatex` solution!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work anymore with Biblatex 3.4 (TeX Live 2016)

Comment: @mankoff do you know an answer to your question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `biblatex` package offers features comparable to those of `multibib`. References from a single `bib` file can be subdivided using various options of `\printbibliography`. Examples include `type`, `keyword` and `category`. Refer to the `biblatex` manual for details. Prefixes to the `labelnumber` are specified with the `prefixnumbers` option.

Assuming each sub-bibliography has a unique prefix, descending label numbers can be obtained by altering the `labelnumber` field format so that it prints the value given by the total prefix-specific entry count, minus the actual `labelnumber`, plus one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,sorting=ydnt,defernumbers]{biblatex}

\AtDataInput{%
  \csnumgdef{entrycount:\strfield{prefixnumber}}{%
    \csuse{entrycount:\strfield{prefixnumber}}+1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}    
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\csuse{entrycount:\strfield{prefixnumber}}+1-#1\relax}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Filler text \cite{aksin,bertram,angenendt}.
Filler text \cite{chiu,padhye,moraux}.
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[prefixnumbers={A},type=article,title={Articles},heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[prefixnumbers={R},type=report,title={Reports},heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[prefixnumbers={P},type=inproceedings,title={Presentations},
                   heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This solution works with either backend, though with `biber` the "rerun LaTeX" messages in the log may not stabilize. In any case heed the warning; the first time the message disappears after recompiling should give the correct document.

Comment: Very nice, but when I try to also cite in the text, things seem a bit odd. I added this just after the `\begin{document}`: `This is a test citation of \cite{aristotle:anima, knuth:ct} and \cite{ctan}.` and it produced: `This is a test citation of [P-2, K0] and [W0].`

Comment: @mankoff Thanks for mentioning this issue. The original solution only worked with `\nocite`. I've made edits to fix this. Anticipate weird results if your categories aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Audrey It seems to me that this solution cannot work with separate `\printbibliography` commands; but as I read the code I think that a user-level command for this would be possible as well. Would that be too much work (probably in order to process all `\printbibliography` options)? Sorry, but my low-level (la)tex skills are non-existent.

Comment: @nplatis Considering this again, I can see now why a solution that doesn't extend `\bibbycategory` would be useful. You might want to add some text between the bibliographies, for example. If you haven't found a solution already, I can post one for your question when I find some time. The above solution and the one I have in mind for you won't work for `sortcites=true`/`numeric-comp` and mixed-category citation lists, however.

Comment: @Audrey Thanks for the reply. That is what I had in mind when asking for separate `\printbibliography` commands. I have not found a solution yet, but I have not  researched it too much.

Comment: @Audrey I'm running this but no reference is printed. I use my own bib file instead of biblatex-examples.bib and use the corresponding paper names.

Answer (score 1):

I have a possible answer (possible because my installation crashed before I can test all of the features). 
It is relying, as mentionned, on `biblatex`, with `biber` as a backend.

In the preamble, you mention that you want to use biber as a back end (useful for tweaking the sorting), that you want to use the new sorting scheme you devised, and that you are going to play with the prefix in the bibliography.

```
\usepackage[defernumbers=true,sorting=reverse,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Yourbibresource}

\DeclareSortingScheme{reverse}{
\sort[direction=descending]{\citeorder}
}
```

At the end of the document, you are printing the different bibliographies with the help of keyword to differentiate between them.

```
\printbibliography[keyword=original,prefixnumbers=F,title=Original sources]

\printbibliography[keyword=known,prefixnumbers=B,title=Other sources]
```

I successfully managed to get the [F1], [F2] and then [B1] and [B2] behavior, but was not able to test the biber tweak due to crashing. However, I am fairly convinced that this is the way to go, due to previous experiments.

I am aware that this answer is not complete as it is not fully tested, but I wanted to launch it out so that people can play with it until I manage to repair my set-up (at work, where I have huge networking trouble, hence possible long duration before repair).

Comment: Did you have a chance to do any further testing? AFAIK this will give descending `labelnumber` to the citations, but prints the bibliography by ascending `labelnumber`.

Comment: I did not do any further testing yet. My config is still out and I can't use biber anymore at work. I could try at home, but I am finishing my thesis, and I don't want to jinx anything at this moment...

Comment: I've finally tested this implementation. It does not mimic the other answer. If the references are sorted newest-first (ascending?), then the numbers are 1..n (descending). Or vice-versa. This is a shame. This implementation is so much more compact than the other solution.