# biblatex: Reverse numbering (i.e., count down)

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I was wondering if it is possible to get the citation numbers to count down

```
[3] newest item
[2] item
[1] oldest item
```

in `biblatex`? I am sorting using either using `sorting=none` and entering in reverse order or using `sorting=ydnt` and I would like the number of the newest (top) entry to be the highest and at the top of the list.

This is for the publications section of a CV.

If needed, a full example can be seen in my [github repo](https://github.com/jberger/Curriculum_Vita/tree/biblatex) for my CV, in the `main.tex` file.

Comment: Section 4.5.1 *Sorting* of the biblatex manual describes the use of the argument `direction=` with values (`ascending` or `descending`) for the `\sort` command.

Comment: @Gonzalo, thanks for that. Now I know that it is at least possible. That would required defining a new sort scheme and also that I use `biber` as a backend. Not the worst case, but would involve some more effort.

Comment: I tried this, but it does not put the numbers in descending order - it simply puts the references in descending order by year (as could be accomplished by unsrt easily). Numbering the values in reverse is the trick needed.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The desired numbering scheme can be achieved by printing the `labelnumber` as the total number of entries in the current reference section, minus the actual label number, plus one.

This approach is demonstrated in the document below. It relies on commands from `etoolbox` and allows for an arbitrary number of reference sections.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

% Count total number of entries in each refsection
\AtDataInput{%
  \csnumgdef{entrycount:\therefsection}{%
    \csuse{entrycount:\therefsection}+1}}

% Print the labelnumber as the total number of entries in the
% current refsection, minus the actual labelnumber, plus one
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}    
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\csuse{entrycount:\therefsection}+1-#1\relax}

\addbibresource[label=biblatex]{biblatex-examples.bib}
\addbibresource[label=base]{xampl.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}[biblatex]
  \nocite{markey,companion,ctan,knuth:ct}
  \printbibliography[title={biblatex examples}]
\end{refsection}
\begin{refsection}[base]
  \nocite{whole-set,inbook-minimal,book-minimal}
  \printbibliography[title={Base examples}]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the document is saved as `doc.tex`, compile with:

```
latex doc
bibtex doc1-blx
bibtex doc2-blx
latex doc
```

With `backend=biber`, there is no need to run `biber` on each of the reference sections. You can also access `bib` files [remotely](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21439/4483) from github.

Some caveats:

- Shorthands. The `labelnumber` is overridden by the `shorthand` field. So with shorthands the maximum `labelnumber` in a given reference section doesn't correspond to the total number of cited entries. To handle this you can clear the `shorthand` field with `biber` by adding the following source map to the preamble:

  ```
  \DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
      \map{\step[fieldset=shorthand,null]}
    }
  }
  ```
- Data-only entries. The code in `\AtDataInput` is executed for each entry in the `bbl` file. This includes related entries or other entries suppressed in the bibliography via `skipbib` or `dataonly`. To omit these from the entry total, you should condition on the `skipbib` setting.

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \def\ifskipbib{\iftoggle{blx@skipbib}}
  \makeatother

  \AtDataInput{\ifskipbib{}{%
    \csnumgdef{entrycount:\therefsection}{\csuse{entrycount:\therefsection}+1}}}
  ```
- Multiple sorting schemes. If your document uses more than one sorting scheme in a reference section, the `bbl` file will contain duplicate entries - one for each scheme. To avoid counting duplicates, you can track the entries already counted in a list.

  ```
  \AtDataInput{%
    \xifinlistcs{\thefield{entrykey}}{entrylist:\therefsection}{}{%
      \listcsxadd{entrylist:\therefsection}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
      \csnumgdef{entrycount:\therefsection}{%
        \csuse{entrycount:\therefsection}+1}}}
  ```
- Multiple versus single `bib` files. Using a single `bib` file for each reference section is convenient, but not necessary - as long as the entries accessed in each section correspond to those printed in the bibliography. For an alternative approach with a single reference section and `labelnumber` prefixes, refer to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37850/4483).

Comment: Excellent work! I will try it out and mark it correct if it works for me. I can't see why it wouldn't though. Thanks!

Comment: Damn, spoke too soon. The problem is that I am doing this with three bibliographies, and this is usually the stumbling block. I will expand my question to include this point too.

Comment: @Joel I've gone ahead and revised my answer. I think it should work for your case now.

Comment: Thanks @Audrey, I will check it out soon. Just as I was posting my edit to my answer (literally) the storm came through Chicago and my power has been out ever since. I appreciate your help, I normally am more responsive. Seeing as I am at my parents to check my email I will not delve into the deep LaTeX magic right now, still thanks for your help!

Comment: and wow, thats cool about biber accessing github. I will def read more about that!

Comment: I was wondering whether Biblatex would be able to make me a cup of coffee, and provide any other services, in the morning?

Comment: Nice work! But If I cite a "related" entry, the numbering is messed up. I have a related entry (related by reprintof relation to another entry in my resume). If I add the related entry the numbering starts at [2]. I can open a new question if you prefer.

Comment: Excellent! However, I am getting alignment issues for >=10 references. It appears that the width of the label is determined based on a label with number <10, such that those >= are too wide. Is there any solution? I can re-ask if needed