# Reverse numbering of bibitems -- moderncv and plainnat

Tags: bibtex, numbering, natbib, moderncv, multibib

I want to number bibliography items in the reverse order -- with `moderncv` and `plainnat` bibliography style.

## Reference:

Enrico's answer at: [Bibtex reverse numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75613/11232)

I tried with Enrico's code, but with `moderncv` and `plainnat` (as I want issn, doi etc). But I could not succeed without any errors and warnings.

Here is the code that does not work at all. Sorry for the big code, but it contains necessary bib data and actual code is at the bottom and is minimal. This needs that `modercv.cls` and `.sty` files (from http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com) be put in the same directory.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% "ModernCV" CV and Cover Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.1 (9/12/12)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%% Important note:  %% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
% This template requires the moderncv.cls and .sty files to be in the same
% directory as this .tex file. These files provide the resume style and themes
% used for structuring the document.

%%%--------------------------Uncomment if bib files are needed---------------------------------%%

%\begin{filecontents}{mypub.bib}
%@Article{johnson-74,
%  author =       "G. B. Johnson",
%  title =        "Enzyme Polymorphism",
%  journal =      "Science",
%  volume =       "184",
%  pages =        "28--37",
%  year =         "1974",
%}
%
%@Article{johnson-howells,
%  author =       "G. B. Johnson and W. W. Howells",
%  title =        "Title title title title title title title title title
%                 title",
%  journal =      "Journal journal journal",
%  year =         "1974",
%}
%
%@Article{johnson-etc,
%  author =       "G. B. Johnson and W. W. Howells and A. N. Other",
%  title =        "Title title title title title title title title title
%                 title",
%  journal =      "Journal journal journal",
%  year =         "1976",
%}
%
%@Manual{anon-67,
%  author =       "Anon.",
%  title =        "Title title title title title title title title title
%                 title",
%  organization = "Organization organization organization",
%  year =         "1967",
%}
%
%@Article{aslin-49,
%  author =       "E. J. Aslin",
%  title =        "Photostat recording in library work",
%  journal =      "Aslib Proceedings",
%  year =         "1949",
%  volume =       "1",
%  pages =        "49--52",
%}
%
%@Article{fletcher-hopkins,
%  author =       "W. M. Fletcher and F. G. Hopkins",
%  title =        "Lactic Acid in Amphibian Muscle",
%  journal =      "J. Physiol.",
%  year =         "1907",
%  volume =       "35",
%  pages =        "247--309",
%}
%
%\end{filecontents}
%%%-conference bib data --------------------------
%\begin{filecontents}{mypub-conf.bib}
%@CONFERENCE{Raja2007a,
%  author = { R. Ganesh and Harish Kumar},
%  title = {Title of the paper Power Industry},
%  booktitle = {39\textsuperscript{th} North American Power Symposium},
%  year = {2007},
%  number = {978-1-4244-1726-1},
%  address = {USA},
%  month = {September 10--14,},
%  organization = {New Mexico State University},
%  publisher = {IEEE},
%  owner = {Anupama},
%  timestamp = {2013.01.26}
%}
%
%@CONFERENCE{Rac2010,
%  author = {R. Rajesh and Harish Kumar},
%  title = {Title of the paper Transfer Capability},
%  booktitle = {International Conference on Computer Applications in Electrical Engineering
%   Recent Advances},
%  year = {2010},
%  address = {Roorkee},
%  month = {February 19--21,},
%  organization = {IIT Roorkee},
%  publisher = {IEEE},
%  owner = {hcl},
%  timestamp = {2013.01.24}
%}
%
%@CONFERENCE{CRa2009,
%  author = {R. Rajesh and Harish Kumar},
%  title = {Title of the paper Using Differential Evolution},
%  booktitle = {International Conference on Control, Automation, Communication and
%   Energy Conservation},
%  year = {2009},
%  address = {Erode},
%  month = {June 4--6,},
%  publisher = {IEEE},
%  owner = {Anupama},
%  timestamp = {2013.01.26}
%}
%
%@CONFERENCE{Raj2007,
%  author = {R. Rajesh and Harish Kumar},
%  title = {Title of the paper deregulated
%   Environment},
%  booktitle = {International Conference on Power Systems},
%  year = {2007},
%  address = {Bangalore},
%  month = {December 12--14,},
%  organization = {Central Power Research Institute},
%  publisher = {IEEE}
%}
%
%@CONFERENCE{CRy2006,
%  author = {R. Rajesh and Harish Kumar},
%  title = {Title of the paper},
%  booktitle = {IEEE Power India Conference},
%  year = {2006},
%  number = {240},
%  address = {New Delhi},
%  month = {April 12--14,},
%  organization = {IIT Delhi},
%  publisher = {IEEE}
%}
%\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{orange}
\usepackage{uri}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{Harish} % Your first name
\familyname{Kumar} % Your last name

% ????????????????? will this be needed???????????????//
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother
%
%% bibliography with mutiple entries
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{journal,conference}{{Journals},{Conferences}}
\usepackage{natbib}
%%%------------------------------------------------------------------
%%% Reverse numbering of bibliography: Enrico's code from -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75613/11232
\usepackage{etaremune}
\makeatletter
\long\def\thebibliography#1{%
  \subsection*{\refname}%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{\@biblabel{#1}}%
  \setlength{\dimen2}{\dimen0}%
  \addtolength{\dimen2}{\labelsep}
  \sloppy
  \clubpenalty 4000
  \@clubpenalty
  \clubpenalty
  \widowpenalty 4000
  \sfcode `\.\@m
  \renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\@biblabel{\theenumiv}} % labels like [3], [2], [1]
  \begin{etaremune}[labelwidth=\dimen0,leftmargin=\dimen2]\@openbib@code
}
\def\endthebibliography{\end{etaremune}}
\def\@bibitem#1{%
  \item \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{#1}{\the\value{enumiv}}}\fi\ignorespaces
}
\makeatother

%%%------------------------------------------------------------------

\listfiles

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
%%------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Publications}
\nocitejournal{*}
\bibliographystylejournal{plainnat}
\bibliographyjournal{mypub}
%
\nociteconference{*}
\bibliographystyleconference{plainnat}
\bibliographyconference{mypub-conf}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

## Question:

How to get an output with references numbered in decreasing order using `moderncv`, `plainnat`, `multibib` all put together in action?

Comment: There is *no* numbering, unless you use the `numbers` option to `natbib`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `natbib` the `thebibliography` environment is defined in a very different way. The following proposal has a limitation: there will no anchor being set for `hyperref`, but it works as requested.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{orange}
\usepackage{uri}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{Harish} % Your first name
\familyname{Kumar} % Your last name

%% bibliography with multiple entries
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{journal,conference}{{Journals},{Conferences}}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%%%------------------------------------------------------------------
%%% Reverse numbering of bibliography
\usepackage{etaremune,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%%% natbib redefines the environment there
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
 {\bibsection\parindent\z@\bibpreamble\bibfont
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{#1.}%
  \setlength{\dimen2}{\dimen0}%
  \addtolength{\dimen2}{\labelsep}
  \begin{etaremune}[labelwidth=\dimen0,leftmargin=\dimen2]
  \ifNAT@openbib
    \renewcommand\newblock{\par}%
  \else
    \renewcommand\newblock{\hskip.11em \@plus .33em \@minus .07em}%
  \fi
  \sloppy
  \clubpenalty4000
  \widowpenalty4000
  \sfcode`\.\@m
  \let\NAT@bibitem@first@sw\@firstoftwo
  \let\citeN\cite\let\shortcite\cite\let\citeasnoun\cite}
 {\bibitem@fin\bibpostamble
  \def\@noitemerr{\PackageWarning{natbib}{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \end{etaremune}
  \bibcleanup}
}%%% end of \AtBeginDocument

%%% patch \@lbibitem to use only \item (for etaremune)
\patchcmd{\@lbibitem}{\item[\hfil\NAT@anchor{#2}{\NAT@num}]}{\item}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
%%------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Publications}
\nocitejournal{*}
\bibliographystylejournal{plainnat}
\bibliographyjournal{mypub}
%
\nociteconference{*}
\bibliographystyleconference{plainnat}
\bibliographyconference{mypub-conf}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will ry it out and get back with results. `:-)`. BTW, how to get the brackets like `[1]` here instead of `1.`?

Comment: Thanks. I got it working. But it was too much hack with natbib. I did it hacking `plainyr.bst` also so as to add issn etc and with your old etaremune code. I have two methods now `:-)`. Thank you.

Comment: How would you add a prefix to each reference section? For instance, having the journals as J6, J5, ... and conferences as C5, C4....