# Is there a way to get reverse numbering on the enumerate environment?

Tags: lists, enumerate

To build a list of publications, I wish to show the most recent on top of the list, while keeping the numbering similar. This can be achieved manually by doing something like:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item[42] pub num 42
\item[41] pub num 41
\item[...]
\item[1] pub num 1
\end{enumerate}
```

but is there a more principled approach?

Comment: See the `etaremune` package. I think there was a question about reverse numbering of bibliographies as well, I'll search. Edit: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58642/bibtex-reverse-numbering/75613#75613

Comment: CTAN also lists `revnumerate`, but I'm afraid it's not included in TL.

Comment: @PauloCereda: it’s `revnum`, and it’s not in tl because the author didn’t provide any statement of the licence — any licence must be listed, as otherwise no-one knows what the licence may be.  (nowadays we might prod the author for a statement of licence, but `revnum` was uploaded in 1998, somewhat before we had started paying detailed attention to the licensing situation.)

Comment: @wasteofspace: Ah I see, thanks! `:)`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The [`etaremune`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etaremune) package provides an `etaremune` environment that does just this. Note that two compile runs is necessary to get the correct numbering.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etaremune}
\begin{document}
\begin{etaremune}
  \item Last things first
  \item \ldots
  \item First things last
\end{etaremune}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem I encountered with etaremune is that I do not seem to be able to change margins and indentation for the list, as I can with the enumerate package.

Comment: @user47979 You could always ask a new question about that problem.

Comment: … and I love the self-explanatory name of the package!

Answer (score 13):

Here's a the first solution that comes to mind. Kind of a hack actually, but it works fine.

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newenvironment{benumerate}[1]{
    \let\oldItem\item
    \def\item{\addtocounter{enumi}{-2}\oldItem}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \setcounter{enumi}{#1}
    \addtocounter{enumi}{1}
}{
    \end{enumerate}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item A  % 1
  \item B  % 2
  \item C  % 3
\end{enumerate}

\begin{benumerate}{9}
  \item A  % 9
  \item B  % 8
  \item C  % 7
\end{benumerate}

\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

The `benumerate` environment expects one mandatory argument: the first number of the list. Ideally you wouldn't have to give it (if you always expect to end the list with 1). But that solution would be a bit more complicated.

Comment: Hm. I'm just now seeing Torbjørn's comment. Of course the `etaremune` package is more elegant than my hack. And more importantly, it has a much funnier name. ;-)

Comment: A somwhat simple approch would be to redefine \theenumi to yse the last value +1 -`\value{enumi};.