# How to enumerate in reverse order

Tags: enumerate, sorting

I want to enumerate Dave-Letterman Style with the last listed first as in enumerating top ten items and having them  listed in  10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1. Is the `etaremune` package the only way to go?

Edit:
I realized my question is vague and incomplete.

Does any package have the ability to change the order of appearance of a collection of entries. Consider a long already-typed list. I may want one of two things,

1. Changing the order of appearance of items. Say it is typed as 1) Apples, 2)Oranges 3)Pears and I want it to appear as 1)Pears, 2)Apples, 3)oranges.  Of course I could cut/paste the original text, but what if the table is long/etc ...
2. Changing the way enumeration shows up as in  1,2,3 vs 3,2,1.

Also, what if a table of items breaks across a page. If all items are on one page then switching the enumeration from 1,2,3 to 3,2,1 would be easy. But if the list breaks across a page then many times it is better to count in reverse. And the question is how do you do this automatically.

Comment: Any specific reason not to use `etaremune`?

Comment: Another alternative would be `revnum`, but in neither case do we have a reason not to use the package.

Comment: @JosephWright  I thought there would be an option to `enumerate`. But, to the main point, eventually I want a list of items that gets split across a page to be automatically done in reverse, and otherwise to be numbered in the usual way.

Comment: If you don't want to use `etaremune`, try http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110263/34355

Comment: It seems to me that you're asking two very different questions here: 1) change the order of the items in a list (not the numbering, but the actual text of the items), and 2) detecting if a page break occurs within a numbered list, and in that case use `etaremune` or similar instead of `enumerate`. Do you want one new environment that can do both things? If not, I think I would edit this question to be about just one of the issues, and create a new question about the other.

Comment: I'm duping here as otherwise the problem is unclear anyway!

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, I think I'd better rewrite this question. It became tangled. I guess reordering a text is somewhat similar to using bibtex, but inside the main body of a document. And changing from enumerate to etaremune at page breaks is totally a separate issue.