# Is there a way to change font or color of specific item to make them appear different?

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize

Say I want to produce something with the effect like this:

```
[\textbf{1}] foo

[\textit{2}] bar

[\color{red} 3] foobar
```

and the numbers should be generated automatically by `\item` in `\enumerate`.

For example, the code should be something like

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item[\bf] foo
    \item[\it] bar
    \item[\red] foobar
\end{enumerate}
```

Thanks.

Some edits:
Both [Bolding a single number in a enumerated list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267952/bolding-a-single-number-in-a-enumerated-list) and [How to modify labels on some (not all) etaremune items](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286730/how-to-modify-labels-on-some-not-all-etaremune-items) seem to provide some useful methods. For example, based on the suggestion in [broken hyperlink to items in etaremune or revnum environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162785/broken-hyperlink-to-items-in-etaremune-or-revnum-environment), I can implement the bold font with proper reference by

```
\providecommand*{\phantomsection}{}% for compatibility if hyperref not loaded
\newcommand{\lebal}{\phantomsection\label}


\begin{etaremune}
\newif\ifitembf
\renewcommand*\labelenumi{[\ifitembf\bfseries\fi\theenumi]}
{\itembftrue \item \lebal{bar} foo}
\end{etaremune}
```

to get a reference to foo, and in the enumerate the item number for is correctly bolded. However, when I use \ref{bar}, the caption in the link seems to be with the correct number but the font is not bolded automatically. Is there a proper solution? Thanks. [I do not have enough reputation to comment on the other questions so I cannot ask there.]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you say "item", do you mean `\item`? It doesn't show in your code.

Comment: Thanks I will try to improve the description.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267952/bolding-a-single-number-in-a-enumerated-list  This seems to be a useful method.

Comment: Another helpful solution with etaremune: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286730/how-to-modify-labels-on-some-not-all-etaremune-items

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you forgot `\item` commands in your question.

Just use `\textcolor`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbf{1}] foo
\item[\textit{2}] bar
\item[\textcolor{red}{3}] foobar
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Miyase, thanks a lot for your reply. Sorry for the impreciseness. This can work but does not seem to help if I need to automatically generate the numbering. Say I have 100 items, this way need to set the values all by myself. But I know which one need to use red color or bold font. I am not sure if the question clearer and thanks again for your kind help.

Comment: @JQK OK, I understand. Please edit your question with this additional information, then I'll see to updating my answer.

Comment: Maybe, one macro managing the formatting of the label would be more useful.