# etaremune with beamer

Tags: beamer, lists, enumerate

I'm trying to use the etaremune package to create an enumerate environment numbered in reverse, as described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110236/is-there-a-way-to-get-reverse-numbering-on-the-enumerate-environment). However it seems that the bullet points do not show up, as can be observed by compiling the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etaremune}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Foo}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item A
  \item B
  \end{enumerate}
  \begin{etaremune}
  \item A
  \item B
  \end{etaremune}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to use etaremune in a beamer document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile at least twice.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etaremune}

\newcommand{\labelenumi}{\textcolor{structure}{\theenumi.}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Foo}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item A
  \item B
  \end{enumerate}

  \begin{etaremune}
  \item A
  \item B
  \end{etaremune}

  \begin{etaremune}
  \item A
  \item B
  \end{etaremune}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]