# Enumerating from highest number to the lowest

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem, line-numbering

I would like to know if there is a way to get an enumerate list in LaTeX such that if I write a total of N items, then I get

```
N. Item numeber N 
N - 1. Item number N - 1
...
1. Item number 1
```

So if N = 3,

```
3. Third item 
2. Second item
1. First item
```

Comment: did the answer meet your requirement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Is there a way to get reverse numbering on the enumerate environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110236/is-there-a-way-to-get-reverse-numbering-on-the-enumerate-environment)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{benumerate}[1]{
    \let\oldItem\item
    \def\item{\addtocounter{enumi}{-2}\oldItem}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \setcounter{enumi}{#1}
    \addtocounter{enumi}{1}
}{
    \end{enumerate}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item A  % 1
  \item B  % 2
  \item C  % 3
\end{enumerate}

\begin{benumerate}{9}
  \item A  % 9
  \item B  % 8
  \item C  % 7
\end{benumerate}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

The `etaremune` package provides an etaremune environment that does just this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etaremune}
\begin{document}
\begin{etaremune}
  \item Last things first
  \item \ldots
  \item First things last
\end{etaremune}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there someway to avoid the indication of the total of items (9 in your answer, N in the OP's notation)?

Comment: please see edit

Comment: You may want to simplify the answer to mention just the `etarenum` approach.

Comment: The problem  encountered with etaremune is that not seem to be able to change margins and indentation for the list, as with the enumerate package--that is why a secondary choice

Comment: @jsbibra - You should mention this shortcoming explicitly, lest the OP has a need for chaging margins, indentation amounts, etc. Of course, the OP may have no such need, in which case `etaremun` is all he/she needs.