# Problem using Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to use `biblatex` to generate a list of publications on my CV.

This works fine, however it doesn't generate the output I wanted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    sorting=ydnt,
    bibstyle=ieee
]{biblatex} %ydnt: Sort by year (descending), name, title.
\addbibresource{MyPublications.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{FirstPaper}
\printbibliography[title={Journal Papers}]
\end{document}
```

Then I tried this, following the example 3.10.4 in [`biblatex` user's guide](ftp://www.ctan.org/ctan/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    sorting=ydnt,
    bibstyle=ieee
]{biblatex} %ydnt: Sort by year (descending), name, title.
\addbibresource{MyPublications.bib}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{primary}
\addtocategory{primary}{FirstPaper}

\begin{document}
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[category=primary,heading=subbibliography,title={Journal Papers}]
\end{document}
```

The code produces an empty document with only a section titled 'References'.

I'm using 64-bit MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXstudio (Windows), however I also tried TeXnicCenter and WinEdt.

BTW, in the second case the `.bbl` file is empty (except for the header), which might give some indication as to what's wrong.

Comment: Have you tried setting `sorting` _after_ `style=ieee`. As the IEEE style has a particular sort order, it sets this in the style. That will override the style you have set if you give it before.

Answer (score 8):

For the first one, could you elaborate on what you want to achieve and what exactly "it doesn't generate the output [you] wanted" means? Probably you should also include either a screenshot or an example `.bib` file.

That the second try does not show anything is clear, because nothing was cited in the document. You could use `\nocite{*}` before `\printbibliography` to display everything in the `.bib` file.

I think it would be more convenient to add a *keyword* to your bibliography entries, which describes the category, e.g. `keywords = {primary}`. Then you wouldn't have to change your tex file every time you add a new bib entry. So all in all it should work like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    sorting=ydnt,
    bibstyle=ieee
]{biblatex} %ydnt: Sort by year (descending), name, title.
\addbibresource{MyPublications.bib}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibheading
    \printbibliography[keyword=primary,heading=subbibliography,title={Journal Papers}]
    \printbibliography[keyword=secondary,heading=subbibliography,title={Books}]
\end{document}
```

But notice also that, if you differentiate your categories by the type of the entries, like paper, book, web link etc. you could even use `\printbibliography[type=book,...]`. (Mentioned also in the user guide you cited)

Comment: I'm trying to write a CV, which means that I'm not citing anything in the document. Basically, I would like to generate a bibliography, divided into several categories (e.g. journal papers, conference papers, etc.) using a .bib file. I would also like the papers to appear in reversed chronological order, with the numbering reset for each category. I had the impression that \addtocategory does the job of \cite.

Answer (score 5):

I am adding this as an answer rather than a comment to canaaerus' answer because it would otherwise be too long.

Even if you are not actually citing anything, you need to use a citation command for Biblatex to process the entries, that's the only way. Your problem has been thought of by the developers who created a `\nocite` command, which does the same job as the usual `\cite`, except it doesn't actually print the citations (just the bibliography).

The `\addtocategory` command adds entries to a specific category in your bibliography (like "Books" or "Journal Papers"), but it does not replace a citation command. It merely flags the entries as belonging to one category or another, and it becomes effective only once they are cited (so you can have a main file defining categories and use it for all of your papers).

In order to sort your entries into sub-categories, the easiest option may be to use `type` and `nottype` (they refer to the entry type, e.g. "book" or "article"), or `keyword` and `notkeyword`, `category` and `notcategory`, etc. You can use several of them in order to fine-tune the sectioning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sorting=ydnt,bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MyPublications.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[type=article,heading=subbibliography,title={Journal Papers}]
\printbibliography[type=book,heading=subbibliography,title={Books}]
\end{document}
```

Regarding the labelling issue, I would suggest you take a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22770/10119). I don't have time to experiment right now, but it should do what you want after you play with it a bit. Note that this solution also implements reverse numbering (I am not sure you want it, but it is consistent with reverse chronological order).