# BibTeX: Separate between Printed and online Sources

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

In the bibliography, I want to separate online references from printed references with the heading online references.
Both references should begin at same page.

I have tried to put the online references in an extra BibTeX file and load both the file with printed and then online references. But LaTeX creates different pages with the bibliographies. I just want one bibliography with at first printed references and then online references with appropriate headings.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can split your bibliography by type: `\printbibliography[type=online]` and `\printbibliography[nottype=online]`. You can use create "subbibliographies" with the option `heading=subbibliography` (`\printbibliography[type=online,heading=subbibliography]` and `\printbibliography[nottype=online,heading=subbibliography]`) and `\printbibheading` before those commands. If that doesn't help, I would really appreciate an MWE to see what is really going on and what you have tried so far.

Comment: See also [How to format bibliography titles as section, subsection, and subsubsection](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134958/35864), [natbib: Split Bibliography Into Sections By Entrytype (without using multibib)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89938/35864), [Problem using Biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60348/35864).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[nottype=online, heading=subbibliography, title={Print Resources}]
\printbibliography[type=online, heading=subbibliography, title={Online Resources}]
```

See the example on p. 111 (§3.11.4 *Subdivided Bibliographies*) of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) which is pretty much the above. For more involved filtering in the bibliography you will want to have a look at §3.6.10 *Bibliography Filters and Checks*.