# Change order of references in bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

I would like to change the order of the references in the bibliography.

My references **order** is like this:

```
[1] Author1Name, Title1
[2] Author2Name, Title2
[3] Author3Name, Title3
```

Now, if I want to change this order? For example let's say that I want to change the 3rd with the 1st. How can I do that?

This is my **code**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric,
sorting=anyt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citation.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Let's cite! Einstein's journal paper \cite{Bsharma2020malnutrition} and Dirac's
book \cite{Azare2021use} are physics-related items. \cite{Ceinstein}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is the **.bib** file:

```
@article{Ceinstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
  keywords =     "physics"
}

@article{Azare2021use,
  title={Use of Machine Learning to Determine the Information Value of a BMI Screening Program},
  author={Zare, Samane and Thomsen, Michael R and Nayga Jr, Rodolfo M and Goudie, Anthony},
  journal={American journal of preventive medicine},
  volume={60},
  number={3},
  pages={425--433},
  year={2021},
  publisher={Elsevier},
}


@article{Bsharma2020malnutrition,
  title={Malnutrition, health and the role of machine learning in clinical setting},
  author={Sharma, Vaibhav and Sharma, Vishakha and Khan, Ayesha and Wassmer, David J and Schoenholtz, Matthew D and Hontecillas, Raquel and Bassaganya-Riera, Josep and Zand, Ramin and Abedi, Vida},
  journal={Frontiers in nutrition},
  volume={7},
  pages={44},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Frontiers},
}
```

I tried to use:

`\usepackage[ backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=anyt ]{biblatex}`

because I wanted to change the order based on the label name. But nothing changed at all.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I edited my question.

Comment: @FateMintTrio Do you mean like a reverse-label sequence: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21401/biblatex-reverse-numbering-i-e-count-down ?

Comment: @Cicada not really. I mean like a custom order.