# biblatex reverse numbering

Tags: biblatex, alignment, sorting

I found [this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22770/132350).
However, I encounter alignment issues with >=10 references.

For example:

[image]

Notice how items >= 10 are indented more than those <9. I would like to follow the (default) same alignment for all items.

Following [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22770/132350) I used:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{library.bib}
@article{foo1,
    author = {Author 1, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}

@article{foo2,
    author = {Author 2, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}

@article{foo3,
    author = {Author 3, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}

@article{foo4,
    author = {Author 4, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}

@article{foo5,
    author = {Author 5, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}

@article{foo6,
    author = {Author 6, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}

@article{foo7,
    author = {Author 7, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}

@article{foo8,
    author = {Author 8, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}

@article{foo9,
    author = {Author 9, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}

@article{foo10,
    author = {Author 10, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}

@article{foo11,
    author = {Author 11, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}
\end{filecontents}

% Count total number of entries in each refsection
\AtDataInput{%
  \csnumgdef{entrycount:\therefsection}{%
    \csuse{entrycount:\therefsection}+1}}

% Print the labelnumber as the total number of entries in the
% current refsection, minus the actual labelnumber, plus one
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\csuse{entrycount:\therefsection}+1-#1\relax}

\addbibresource[label=myname]{library.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}[myname]
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography[title={My title}]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `biblatex` needs to measure the width of the numeric labels for correct alignment. This usually happens when an entry is read from the `.bbl` file. Since the numbering changes depending on the number of entries in the `.bbl` file, the width measurement obtained at data input is incorrect.

The quickest solution with a modern `biblatex` is probably to pass the option `locallabelwidth` to `printbibliography`. That way the required width measurements are performed locally (for this specific bibliography only) when all the numbering is fixed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

% Count total number of entries in each refsection
\AtDataInput{%
  \csnumgdef{entrycount:\therefsection}{%
    \csuse{entrycount:\therefsection}+1}}

% Print the labelnumber as the total number of entries in the
% current refsection, minus the actual labelnumber, plus one
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\csuse{entrycount:\therefsection}+1-#1\relax}


\begin{filecontents}{library.bib}
@article{foo1,
    author = {Author 1, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}
@article{foo2,
    author = {Author 2, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}
@article{foo3,
    author = {Author 3, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}
@article{foo4,
    author = {Author 4, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}
@article{foo5,
    author = {Author 5, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}
@article{foo6,
    author = {Author 6, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}
@article{foo7,
    author = {Author 7, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}
@article{foo8,
    author = {Author 8, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}
@article{foo9,
    author = {Author 9, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}
@article{foo10,
    author = {Author 10, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}
@article{foo11,
    author = {Author 11, A.},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-234}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource[label=myname]{library.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}[myname]
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography[title={My title},locallabelwidth]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

[image: Nicely aligned label numbers.]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Who would have though the solution to be that simple