# Citing a certain type of reference using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I am in the process of updating my CV using LaTeX. In my CV, I have a list of publications, reports, etc., and I would like to use `biblatex` to manage these lists.  Currently, all of my publications are maintained in a single `.bib` file, and ideally, I want it to stay this way.

Here is a simple example of how I would like my publications printed in my CV, where the largest labelnumber also equals the total number of references in a particular section:

> Publications & Presentations
>  JOURNAL ARTICLES
>  [3] Author, A.;
>   Author, B. Journal Article 1 ...
>  [2] Author, C.; Author, D.
>   Journal Article 2 ...
>  [1] Author, E.; Author, F. Journal Article 3
>   ...
>
> REPORTS
>  [2] Author, G.; Author, H. Report 1 ...
>  [1] Author,
>   I.; Author, J. Report 2 ...

I can separate the reference types using `\defbibfilter` and `\printbibliography[filter=...]`.  However, the only way I can get the references to print in the bibliography without a citation is with `\nocite{*}`.  When I use `\nocite{*}`, all of the references in my `.bib` file are added to the `.bbl` file so that the labelnumbers are larger than the actual number of references for a particular type.  For example, if there are 8 total references in the `.bib` file, with 4 articles and 4 reports, the bibliography prints as:

> Publications & Presentations
>  JOURNAL ARTICLES
>  [8] Author,
>   Author ...
>  [7] Author, Author ...
>  [6] Author, Author ...
>   [5] Author, Author ...
>
> REPORTS
>  [8] Author...
>  [7] Author...
>  [6] Author...
>  [5]
>   Author...

Is there any way to `\nocite` only certain types of references in the `.bib` file?  For example, `\nocite{type=article}`?  Or is there another `biblatex` command that will allow me to cite a particular entry type (`article`, `report`, `book`, etc.) rather than citing with a citation key?

Comment: Its not completely clear to me what you want to achieve. Do you want consecutive numbers (Journal Articles 1-4, Reports 5-8)? In this case try `[defernums=true]` in the package options. Or do you want to have numbers start at 1 for each type? In that case try "Bibliography Sections" (§3.5.3 in the manual).

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21401/biblatex-reverse-numbering-i-e-count-down

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23117/biblatex-get-rid-of-issn-urls-and-dois-in-references/23118#23118

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A descending `labelnumber` in the bibliography is easy to obtain when entries for the subbibliographies are drawn from separate `bib` files. The problem is addressed [in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21401/4483).

Like any citation command, `\nocite` makes bibliographic data available to `biblatex`. It can't be limited to `entrytype` *a priori* unless you pass a list of entry keys that are `entrytype`-specific. For example:

```
\nocite{<articlekey1>, <articlekey2>, <articlekey3>, ...}
...
\nocite{<reportkey1>, <reportkey2>, <reportkey3>, ...}
```

Descending `labelnumber` with one `bib` file can be obtained by making the item counters `entrytype`-specific. An easy way to perform counting and printing by `entrytype` is to modify `\bibbycategory`. The code below demonstrates this approach. It assumes that bibliographic data are made available only via `\nocite`.

Extensions to flexible `category` definitions and all citation commands are possible. For an illustration, see [this previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37850/4483).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=ydnt,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}

\makeatletter

% Print labelnumber as actual number, plus item total, minus one
\newrobustcmd{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\csuse{bbx@itemtotal}+1-#1\relax}

% Initialize category counters
\def\bbx@initcategory#1{\csnumgdef{bbx@count@#1}{0}}
\forlistloop{\bbx@initcategory}{\blx@categories}

% Increment category counters
\def\bbx@countcategory#1{%
  \ifentrytype{#1}
    {\csnumgdef{bbx@count@#1}{\csuse{bbx@count@#1}+1}%
     \addtocategory{#1}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
     \listbreak}
    {}}
\AtDataInput{\forlistloop{\bbx@countcategory}{\blx@categories}}

% Modify \bibbycategory to set item total
\patchcmd{\blx@bibcategory}
  {\blx@key@heading{#1}}
  {\blx@key@heading{#1}%
   \csnumdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{0}%
   \csnumgdef{bbx@itemtotal}{\csuse{bbx@count@#1}}}
  {}{}

\makeatother

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{article}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{report}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{inproceedings}

\defbibheading{bibliography}{\section*{Publications and Presentations}}
\defbibheading{article}{\subsection*{Journal Articles}}
\defbibheading{report}{\subsection*{Reports}}
\defbibheading{inproceedings}{\subsection*{Presentations}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{aksin,bertram,chiu,companion,padhye,angenendt,moraux}
\printbibheading
\bibbycategory
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Audrey!  This is exactly what I was looking for ... I am new to Latex (and BibTex, BibLatex), but, so far I love it!  Hopefully, sometime in the future I'll understand the code enough to help others as you have helped me.

Comment: @Shanna You're welcome! Much of the code relies on commands from `etoolbox`. `biblatex` depends on this package, so we don't need to load it in the preamble.

Comment: i use miktex, but doesn't work.... =(

Comment: @ros The solution needs an extra `latex` run. If you have `biblatex 2.0` and don't want to use `biber` as the backend, load `biblatex` with the option setting `backend=bibtex`. If this doesn't help, you'll have to provide some details.

Comment: Doesn't work with Biblatex 3.4 (TeX Live 2016)