# Reverse Numbering with Biblatex and Moderncv

Tags: biblatex, moderncv

This question is a follow-up to an [earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123805/creating-bibliographies-with-biblatex-and-moderncv). I'm using ModernCV with Biblatex to make my CV. I've used the solution given to create a list of publications, sorted by type and by year.

My question is how I can reverse the numbering of the publications (highest first) without changing anything else. [Solutions exist](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21401/biblatex-reverse-numbering-i-e-count-down) for how to do this from multiple .bib files and I may consider that option if this is impossible, but an option where I could continue using a single bib file would be ideal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just wish to reverse the numbering - not the order - then you can use the following approach:

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{biblatex,refcount}

\makeatletter
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66829/5764
\newcounter{numbibentries}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\stepcounter{numbibentries}\finentry}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123805/5764
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{% label format from numeric.bbx
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \number\numexpr\getrefnumber{num-bib-entries}-\abx@field@labelnumber+1\relax}}
     {\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}% layout parameters from moderncvstyleclassic.sty
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{\hintscolumnwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \leftmargin\labelwidth%
      \advance\leftmargin\labelsep}%
      \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\AtEndDocument{% Add reference at end of document to remember number of bib-entries.
  \edef\@currentlabel{\thenumbibentries}\label{num-bib-entries}}
\makeatother

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\nocite{companion,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography[title={Publications}]
\end{document}
```

The idea is to [count the number of references by tapping into each "`\bibitem`"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66829/5764). Once all is counted, we insert a `\label` at the end of the document (using `\AtEndDocument`). This label is retrieved and used in a calculation (thanks to the expandable `\getrefnumber` from [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount)) to reverse the numbering.

---

For multiple bibliographies per document, you could use `\citesinthissection{<num>}` as defined below:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\citesinthissection}[1]{\xdef\@totalcites{#1}}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123805/5764
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{% label format from numeric.bbx
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \number\numexpr\@totalcites-\abx@field@labelnumber+1\relax}}
     {\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}% layout parameters from moderncvstyleclassic.sty
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{\hintscolumnwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \leftmargin\labelwidth%
      \advance\leftmargin\labelsep}%
      \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\makeatother

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\nocite{companion,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\citesinthissection{3}% There are 3 cites in this section
\printbibliography[notkeyword=primary,title={Publications}]
\nocite{aristotle:anima,aristotle:physics}
\citesinthissection{2}% There are 2 cites in this section
\printbibliography[keyword=primary,resetnumbers=true,title={Other Publications}]
\end{document}
```

Remember to update the count of items whenever you add elements to your bibliography.  Use the `defernumbers=true` global option and `resetnumbers=true` option from the second `\printbibliography` onwards.  You may need to use options like `keyword`/`notkeyword` options in order to print exactly only what you want in each bibliography part.

Comment: This answer works well. However, I have multiple categories (say inproceedings and article). I can use something like '\printbibliography[type=article,heading=subbibliography,title={Journal Articles}]' to print each section separately. However, I'd like to be able to reset the counter for each section. If I use the additional option ',resetnumbers=true' then each section's numbering begins at N, where N is the number of references across all sections, rather than the number of references in the particular subsection.

Comment: @mbarete: I see. An easy fix here would be to _remove_ my automated approach and introduce some manual insertions. For example, if you know how many references you'll have in each section, one can precede a `\printbibliography` with something like `\citesinthissection`. That is, `\citesinthissection{4} \printbibliography[..]` ... `\citesinthissection{7} \printbibliography[..]` ...

Comment: Is there a way to combine this solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43476/citing-a-certain-type-of-reference-using-biblatex with the formatting for moderncv? If not then continuous numbering is a second-best fit.

Comment: @mbarete: I've added my `\citesinthissection` suggestion.

Comment: I improved the code for multiple bibliography.  The previous one didn't really work.