# Separate biblatex biblios, descending numbering, 'check' filters

Tags: biblatex

I would like to produce multiple bibliographies in a CV, separating papers that have no dates from those with dates (one way to tell if they are 'under review' or 'published' - I realise there are other ways to do this, such as keywords etc.). The same for conference papers.

With the changes to `biblatex`, my old code no longer works. I managed to make some progress using the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367163/separate-biblatex-bibliographies-with-newest-entry-and-highest-reference-number), ie, I do have separate bibliographies for journals papers and conferences with descending numbering, *if* I don't filter the empty-date entries.

I am filtering the entries produced by `\printbibligraphy` using 'check', which works, but is not compatible with the counters used for the descending numbering  (ie, it does not exclude the 'filtered' papers).

How do I go about modifying the code below to fix the counters?

Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[czech,english]{babel}  
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,defernumbers=true,sorting=keysort]{biblatex}


%%%%%%%%%%%%
% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367163/separate-biblatex-bibliographies-with-newest-entry-and-highest-reference-number:
% does not work correctly due to 'check' in bibliographies...

% Count total number of entries in each refsection
\AtDataInput{%
  \ifcsundef{bbx@processedentries:\therefsection}
    {\csgdef{bbx@processedentries:\therefsection}{}}
    {}%
  \xifinlistcs{\thefield{entrykey}}{bbx@processedentries:\therefsection}{}{%
    \listcsxadd{bbx@processedentries:\therefsection}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
    \csnumgdef{bbx@entrycount:\therefsection:\thefield{entrytype}}{%
      \csuse{bbx@entrycount:\therefsection:\thefield{entrytype}}+1}}}

% Print the labelnumber as the total number of entries in the
% current refsection, minus the actual labelnumber, plus one
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}    
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\csuse{bbx@entrycount:\therefsection:\thefield{entrytype}}+1-#1\relax}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareSortingScheme{keysort}{
\sort[direction=descending]{\field{entrykey}  }
}

\addbibresource{pubs1.bib}
\addbibresource{pubs2.bib}

\begin{document}

\defbibcheck{confnoyear}{ \ifentrytype{inproceedings} {\iffieldundef{year}{}{\skipentry}} {\skipentry} }
\defbibcheck{journoyear}{ \ifentrytype{article}       {\iffieldundef{year}{}{\skipentry}} {\skipentry} }
\defbibcheck{confwyear}{  \ifentrytype{inproceedings} {\iffieldundef{year}{\skipentry}{}} {\skipentry} }
\defbibcheck{jourwyear}{  \ifentrytype{article}       {\iffieldundef{year}{\skipentry}{}} {\skipentry} }

% Journal papers under review (w/out years)
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=JS,sorting=keysort]
\printbibliography[check=journoyear]   \nocite{*}

% Journals published
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=J,sorting=keysort]
\printbibliography[check=jourwyear] \nocite{*}

% Conf papers under review (w/out years)
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=CS,sorting=keysort]
\printbibliography[check=confnoyear] \nocite{*}

% Conf papers published 
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=C,sorting=keysort]
\printbibliography[check=confwyear] \nocite{*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @moewe I'm running your code but no references appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This answer was written in 2018 and may no longer work as intended on newer systems.
> Refer to [Reverse numbering in biblatex with customized bibchecks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/625213/35864) for an answer that works with `biblatex` v3.16 (2020-12-31).

The answer to [Separate Biblatex bibliographies with newest entry and highest reference number at the top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367163/35864) and Audrey's answer to [Multibib reverse label or sort order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9768/35864), from which it derives, count the numbers of items in each refsection and then calculate the backwards label number from that. As you rightfully point out, your bibchecks skip over several entries that are still part of the refsection, so this approach leads to discontinuous numbering.

Here is a completely different approach. A solution for you set-up must be based on the specific bibliography environment since we need to count the maximum number of items in each bibliography environment to be able to count backwards in each bibliography.

For each bibliography environment we count the number of items in the list and write it to the `.aux` file so it is available at the beginning of the list in the next run. Then if the number of items is available at the beginning of the list, we recalculate the `labelnumber` based on the maximum number of items in the current bibliography. Finally that new `labelnumber` must be registered as the official `labelnumber` of the current item.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[czech,english]{babel}  
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,defernumbers=true,sorting=keysort]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{bibenvcounter}
\newcounter{bibitemcounter}[bibenvcounter]

\newcommand*{\auxkacz@envmax}[2]{%
  \csgdef{blxkacz@envmax@#1}{#2}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\stepcounter{bibenvcounter}%
   \list
     {\ifcsundef{blxkacz@envmax@\the\value{bibenvcounter}}
        {}
        {\numdef\abx@field@localnumber{%
           \csuse{blxkacz@envmax@\the\value{bibenvcounter}}%
             -\value{bibitemcounter}}%
         \csundef{blx@defer@\the\c@refsection
            @\blx@refcontext@context
            @\abx@field@entrykey}%
         \blx@thelabelnumber}%
      \stepcounter{bibitemcounter}%
      \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist
   \blx@auxwrite\@mainaux{}{%
     \string\auxkacz@envmax
       {\the\value{bibenvcounter}}
       {\the\value{bibitemcounter}}}}
  {\item}
\makeatother

\defbibcheck{confnoyear}{ \ifentrytype{inproceedings} {\iffieldundef{year}{}{\skipentry}} {\skipentry} }
\defbibcheck{journoyear}{ \ifentrytype{article}       {\iffieldundef{year}{}{\skipentry}} {\skipentry} }
\defbibcheck{confwyear}{  \ifentrytype{inproceedings} {\iffieldundef{year}{\skipentry}{}} {\skipentry} }
\defbibcheck{jourwyear}{  \ifentrytype{article}       {\iffieldundef{year}{\skipentry}{}} {\skipentry} }

\DeclareSortingScheme{keysort}{
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{entrykey}}
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{a,
  author  = {Author, A.},
  title   = {A Title},
  date    = {1980},
}
@inproceedings{b,
  author  = {Buthor, B.},
  title   = {B Title},
  date    = {1980},
}
@inproceedings{c,
  author  = {Buthor, C.},
  title   = {C Title},
  date    = {1980},
}
@inproceedings{d,
  author  = {Duthor, D.},
  title   = {A Title},
}
@inproceedings{e,
  author  = {Euthor, E.},
  title   = {B Title},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=CS,sorting=keysort]
\printbibliography[check=confnoyear] \nocite{*}

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=C,sorting=keysort]
\printbibliography[check=confwyear] \nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography 1 shows "[CS2] E. Euthor, “B title”.//[CS1] D. Duthor, “A title”." Bibliography 2 has "[C3] C. Buthor, “C title”, 1980.//[C2] B. Buthor, “B title”, 1980.//[C1] A. Author, “A title”, 1980."]

Comment: I'm running the code but I get no references. What could be the reason? Do I need to have a separate bib file?

Comment: @Bob I just ran the code from the answer and got exactly the same output as shown in the picture. There are several things that could have gone wrong at your end. Can you run a simple document using `biblatex` and Biber? (Try https://gist.github.com/moewew/6e738db2c03f1e1a2653e33d3101b524 and do not modify anything in that file). Do you get any warnings or errors in the `.log` or `.blg` files?

Comment: when I'm running the suggested file, I get a page with "sigfridsson"

Comment: @Bob Did you run Biber on your file? You need to compile it with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help on getting your editor to run Biber instead of BibTeX for you.

Comment: I ran using Biber based on tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 but still, I only get "sigfridsson"

Comment: @Bob Delete all auxiliary files, then run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX in that order. If you still don't get any output, please show me the `.log` and `.blg` files. Upload them to a text-sharing website such as pastebin or GitHub Gists.

Comment: The order LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX  is not clear to me. In TeXstudio, for bibliography tool, I only have  Biber, BibTex, and BibTex 8bit,

Comment: @Bob LaTeX is not a bibliography tool, so you won't find it in there. It is just the normal engine you use to compile your LaTeX document. You can probably run it by clicking the green arrow.

Comment: I put the file here: https://gist.github.com/wereHamster/772010/e199a581c403687158838245ba3892a556745b79?signup=true#gistcomment-3119726

Comment: @Bob That looks good. According to the `.blg` Biber finds the entry and LaTeX finds the `.bbl` file, so you should see the expected output: "Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998".

Comment: but I can even see the pdf now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102528/discussion-between-moewe-and-bob).

Comment: I had to change `\abx@field@localnumber` to `\abx@field@labelnumber`. With `localnumber`, the entries are listed as CS2, CS4, C2, C4, C6. With `labelnumber` the result is as in the screenshot.