# Separate bibliographies with global labels

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I have several categories of bibliographic entries which I would like to present satisfying the following requirements:

1. Each category goes into its own subsection (for example, journal articles, books, etc.) of my "Bibliography" section.
2. I would like to have entries in each category numbered separately and in reverse, for example [J10]-[J1], [B3]-[B1] etc.
3. Different types of my entries do not necessarily correspond to different `bibtex` types (for example, `@article` entries may be split into two categories). I find it easiest to keep the entries of each category in a separate `.bib` file.
4. References to the various bibliographic entries may appear anywhere in the text.

All requirements apart from (4) can be satisfied if each category corresponds to a separate `refsection` (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21401/biblatex-reverse-numbering-i-e-count-down) for requirement (2), just add the option `prefixnumbers` when printing each bibliography). Unfortunately, `refsection`s seem only to produce local labels and therefore each entry can only be referenced inside its own `refsection`.

If the above is correct, `refsection`s cannot be used, and some other way of segregating entries will be required, for example by keywords or using `biblatex` *categories*. But then I don't see how the solution to (2) can be applied since it seems tied to `refsection`s.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without reference sections, the separate `bib` files don't help. You could adapt [this previous answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37850/4483), but you need to be able to distinguish between the categories from the bibliographic data - not from file membership.

Comment: Thank you @Audrey! I believe I can live with (=accept) categories; separate files could probably still be used, with the help of [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35779/6480) answer. I hadn't been able to locate the answer you point to, probably because it referes to `biblatex` only in the answer.

Comment: Ah, good point. I forgot about that answer from PLK. The question I linked asked for a `multbib` solution. I was hesitant to retag it because the OP didn't accept my answer. Feel free to answer your own question once you put together a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the categories are indicated in the `usera` field, the following document demonstrates how you can meet requirements 1, 2 and 4.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,defernumbers,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

% Store value passed to category option for \printbibliography
\apptocmd{\blx@key@category}{\edef\bbx@thecategory{\detokenize{#1}}}{}{}

% Initialize category counters
\def\bbx@initcategory#1{\csnumgdef{bbx@count@#1}{0}}
\forlistloop{\bbx@initcategory}{\blx@categories}

% Increment category counters
\def\bbx@countcategory#1{%
  \iffieldequalstr{usera}{#1}
    {\csnumgdef{bbx@count@#1}{\csuse{bbx@count@#1}+1}%
     \addtocategory{#1}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
     \listbreak}
    {}}
\AtDataInput{\forlistloop{\bbx@countcategory}{\blx@categories}}

% Print labelnumber as actual number, plus item total, minus one
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \ifcitation
    {\number\numexpr\csuse{bbx@count@\thefield{usera}}+1-#1\relax}
    {\number\numexpr\csuse{bbx@count@\bbx@thecategory}+1-#1\relax}}

\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@Periodical{jcg,
  title = {Computers and Graphics},
  issuetitle = {Semantic {3D} Media and Content},
  volume = {35},
  number = {4},
  year = {2011},
  issn = {0097-8493}}
@Article{sarfraz,
  author = {M. Sarfraz and M. F. A. Razzak},
  title = {An algorithm for automatic capturing of the font outlines},
  journal = {Computers and Graphics},
  volume = {26},
  number = {5},
  pages = {795--804},
  year = {2002},
  issn = {0097-8493},
  doi = {10.1016/S0097-8493(02)00134-6}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{primary}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{secondary}

\defbibheading{bibliography}{\section*{Bibliography}}
\defbibheading{primary}{\subsection*{Primary references}}
\defbibheading{secondary}{\subsection*{Secondary references}}

\begin{document}
Filler text \parencite{companion,cms,sarfraz,nussbaum}.
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[heading=primary,category=primary,prefixnumbers={P}]
Filler text \parencite{ctan}.
\printbibliography[heading=secondary,category=secondary,prefixnumbers={S}]
Filler text \parencite{jcg}.\par\pagebreak
Filler text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to a [previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35779/6480) from PLK, requirement 3 can be supported with biber. The following `sourcemap` adds the data needed in the `usera` field. Just save this in a separate file called `biber.conf`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" bmap_overwrite="1">
      <map>
        <per_datasource>biblatex-examples.bib</per_datasource>
        <map_step map_field_set="USERA" map_field_value="primary"/>
      </map>
      <map>
        <per_datasource>test.bib</per_datasource>
        <map_step map_field_set="USERA" map_field_value="secondary"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

Some caveats:

- The new format typically needs an extra `latex` run to get the label numbers right, even if biblatex doesn't tell you to "rerun LaTeX".
- The new format will generally screw up citation labels with the `sortcites=true` or `style=numeric-comp` option settings, unless all citation lists are limited to a single category. The citation list in the sample document, for example, doesn't meet this condition.