# Biblatex with sections, prefix, and reversed order

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting

I'm trying to use biblatex to obtain a bibliography with the following characteristics: 1) it should be divided into two sections (i.e., "Journal Papers" and "Conference Papers"); 2) each entry in the first (resp. second) section should have a prefix "J" (resp. "C"); 3) the entries should be in reversed order.

So far, I've been able to achieve points 1) and 3) above, but not point 2), that is, I obtain

```
Journal Papers
[2]
[1]

Conference Papers
[2]
[1]
```

instead of

```
Journal Papers
[J2]
[J1]

Conference Papers
[C2]
[C1]
```

Here's my MWE, which is inspired by other similar topics (namely, [biblatex: Reverse numbering (i.e., count down)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21401/biblatex-reverse-numbering-i-e-count-down) and [Multibib reverse label or sort order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9768/multibib-reverse-label-or-sort-order)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=ieee,sorting=ydnt,defernumbers]{biblatex}

\AtDataInput{%
  \csnumgdef{entrycount:\therefsection}{%
    \csuse{entrycount:\therefsection}+1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}    
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\csuse{entrycount:\therefsection}+1-#1\relax}

\addbibresource[label=journals]{my_publications.bib}
\addbibresource[label=conferences]{my_publications.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}[journals]
  \nocite{journal1,journal2}
  \printbibliography[prefixnumbers={J},title={Journal Papers}]
\end{refsection}
\begin{refsection}[conferences]
  \nocite{conf1,conf2}
  \printbibliography[prefixnumbers={C},title={Conference Papers}]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

I compile using the following commands:

```
latex doc
bibtex doc1-blx
bibtex doc2-blx
latex doc
pdflatex doc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, I'm using the MacTeX-2016 Distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use prefixnumber anymore. You should use 
`\newrefcontext[labelprefix=J]` on the line above printbiliography.