# biblatex sorting by date

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I have written my own biblatex style for citing jurisdiction. I realized that the sorting in the bibliography is not chronological within the years. I addressed the date field to each bibliography item and it seems as if only the year is considered. Consulting the manual made me believe that there is presently no way to use the date field for sorting.

My question is if anyone has a suggestion for how to use the other sort fields to get the jurisdictions sorted in the correct order by hand?

I know that this is far away from a smart solution but I my thesis is due on monday in a week.

So I appreciate an suggestions.

Minimal example:

```
\listfiles   
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}   
\usepackage{textcomp} % Zusätzliche Symbole   
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes} %  
\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=biber,sorting=nyt,date=short,]{biblatex} 


\DeclareFieldFormat[jurisdiction]{number}{\RN{#1}}  
\DeclareFieldFormat{institution}{#1}  
\DeclareFieldFormat{origdate}{#1}  
\newbibmacro*{usera}{  
  \iffieldundef{usera}  
    {}  
    {\printfield{usera}}}  

\newbibmacro*{institution}{%  
  \printlist{institution}%  
  \setunit*{\addspace}%  
  }

\newbibmacro*{number}{%  
  \iffieldundef{number}  
    {}%  
    {\printfield{number}}}  

\newbibmacro*{vom}{
   \printtext{v.}%
   \setunit*{\addspace}%
   }

\newbibmacro*{journaltitle}{  
 \iffieldundef{shortjournal}%  
    {\printfield{journaltitle}}%  
    {\printfield{shortjournal}}%  
  }

\newbibmacro*{note+pages}{%  
  \printfield{note}%  
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%  
  \printfield{pages}%  
  \newunit  
}

\newbibmacro*{origdate}{\printorigdate}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{jurisdiction}{%  
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%  
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%  
  \usebibmacro{institution}%  
  \usebibmacro{vom}%  
  \usebibmacro{date}%  
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock  
  \usebibmacro{usera}  
  \newunit  
  \usebibmacro{journaltitle}  
  \setunit*{\addspace}  
  \usebibmacro{number}  
  \setunit{\addspace}  
  \usebibmacro{origdate}  
  \newunit  
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}  
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock  
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%  
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}  




\bibliography{Literatur} % Einbinden der bibliographischen Daten. 

\begin{filecontents}{Literatur.bib}  
@jurisdiction{bmf1998,  
  institution = {BMF-Schr.},  
  date = {1998-03-25},  
  shortjournal = {BStBl.},  
  origdate = {1998},  
  number = {1},  
  usera = {},  
  pages = {268--344}  
}  

@jurisdiction{bmf2000a,
  institution = {BMF-Schr.},
  date = {2000-03-29},
  shortjournal = {BStBl.},
  origdate = {2000},
  number = {1},
  usera = {},
  pages = {462--463}
}

@jurisdiction{bmf2000b,
  institution = {BMF-Schr.},
  date = {2000-10-05},
  shortjournal = {BStBl.},
  origdate = {2000},
  number = {1},
  usera = {},
  pages = {1383--1390}
}

@jurisdiction{bmf2000c,
  institution = {BMF-Schr.},
  date = {2000-07-18},
  shortjournal = {BStBl.},
  origdate = {2000},
  number = {1},
  usera = {},
  pages = {1198}
}

@jurisdiction{bmf2000d,
  institution = {BMF-Schr.},
  date = {2000-02-25},
  shortjournal = {BStBl.},
  origdate = {2000},
  number = {1},
  usera = {},
  pages = {372--375}
}

@jurisdiction{bmf2001,
  institution = {BMF-Schr.},
  date = {2001-06-07},
  shortjournal = {BStBl.},
  origdate = {2001},
  number = {1},
  usera = {},
  pages = {367}
}

@jurisdiction{bmf2004,
  institution = {BMF-Schr.},
  date = {2004-11-26},
  shortjournal = {BStBl.},
  origdate = {2004},
  number = {1},
  usera = {},
  pages = {1190--1191}
}

@jurisdiction{bmf2004a,
  institution = {BMF-Schr.},
  date = {2004-03-26},
  shortjournal = {BStBl.},
  origdate = {2004},
  number = {1},
  usera = {},
  pages = {434--441}
}

@jurisdiction{bmf2008,
  institution = {BMF-Schr.},
  date = {2008-07-04},
  shortjournal = {BStBl.},
  origdate = {2008},
  number = {1},
  usera = {},
  pages = {718--729}
}

@jurisdiction{bmf2008,
  institution = {BMF-Schr.},
  date = {2008-08-11},
  shortjournal = {BStBl.},
  origdate = {2008},
  number = {1},
  usera = {},
  pages = {838--845}
}

@jurisdiction{bmf2009,
  institution = {BMF-Schr.},
  date = {2009-05-20},
  shortjournal = {BStBl.},
  origdate = {2009},
  number = {1},
  usera = {},
  pages = {671--672}
}

@jurisdiction{bmf2009a,
  institution = {BMF-Schr.},
  date = {2009-03-26},
  shortjournal = {BStBl.},
  origdate = {2009},
  number = {1},
  usera = {},
  pages = {514}
}

@jurisdiction{bmf2009b,
  institution = {BMF-Schr.},
  date = {2009-02-24},
  shortjournal = {BStBl.},
  origdate = {2009},
  number = {1},
  usera = {},
  pages = {440--444}
}

@jurisdiction{bmf2010,
  institution = {BMF-Schr.},
  date = {2010-04-16},
  shortjournal = {BStBl.},
  origdate = {2010},
  number = {1},
  usera = {},
  pages = {354--367}
}

@jurisdiction{bmf2011,
  institution = {BMF-Schr.},
  date = {2011-07-11},
  shortjournal = {BStBl.},
  origdate = {2011},
  number = {1},
  usera = {},
  pages = {713--715}
}

@jurisdiction{bmf2011a,
  institution = {BMF-Schr.},
  date = {2011-11-11},
  shortjournal = {BStBl.},
  origdate = {2011},
  number = {1},
  usera = {},
  pages = {1314--1415},
}

@jurisdiction{bmf2011b,
  institution = {BMF-Schr.},
  date = {2011-12-08},
  shortjournal = {BStBl.},
  origdate = {2011},
  number = {1},
  usera = {},
  pages = {1279--1286}
}
\end{filecontents}

% ================================================================================================== 
% Beginn des eigentlichen Dokuments. 
\begin{document} 

\nocite{*}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you add some examples, with a minimal preamble, of what you have? How you're calling biblatex and a handful of bibliography items.

Comment: That makes little sence. Because I use a biblatex style that has been completely coded by myself. I just need to understand how I can use the sort*-fields to sort certain bib entrys by hand. My idea is to address each of those jurisdiction items a number in the bib file via one of the sorting fields. And biblatex should sort these items in order of the numbers addressed.  And please excuse my poor english. And I call biblatex with biber and the sorting option nyt but I need this sorting for my articles and books.

Comment: It seems that addressing a number to the presort field can be used to sort the items in the appropriate order. But of course this is everything but not smart.

Comment: Maybe you could find a way to work it if you follow the instructions on p. 139 s. of the `biblatex` documentation. There is an example of a new sorting scheme on p. 141 – maybe you could use the date field there. Note that you need biber as a backend. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Somebody implemented sorting by months in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33332/10434 Maybe that helps you? I'd suggest you set up a minimal working example, because it's a lot of guessing otherwise.

Comment: I will try to get an minimal example running for you. I appreciate your help. It isn't that pressing anymore because I found the work around via the presort field. But for my next project I'd like to have it working automatically. Hence I'll try to implement/find a better solution. The link above might be very useful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Edited by [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe) (2018-07-14) to conform with the new names and sorting template definitions of `biblatex` >= v3.8. See the edit history for older versions.

Under any of the predefined sorting schemes, you can override the order of the bibliography using the `presort` and `sortkey` fields. The `presort` field is intended to group entries together in the bibliography. The `sortkey` field serves as a master sort key.

From the appendix the biblatex manual, you can see that the predefined sorting schemes establish chronology only with the `year` and `volume` fields. With biber as the backend you can use `\DeclareSortingTemplate` to also consider `month` and `day`. When data are not available, fallback values can be specified with `\literal{<value>}`. Otherwise "small" fallback values are used.

Here I've defined a new sorting scheme based on `nyt` from `biblatex.def`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nymdt]{biblatex}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{nymdt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
    \literal{00}
  }
  \sort{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
    \literal{00}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
  }
  \sort{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
    \literal{0000}
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{ref1,
  author = {Lastname, Firstname},
  title = {Article entry with presort field},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume = {12},
  date = {2001-01/2001-02},
  pages = {92--122},
  presort = {A}}
@Book{ref2,
  author = {Lastname, Firstname},
  title = {A book entry with presort field},
  year = {2001},
  month = feb,
  day = {11},
  presort = {A}}
@Book{ref3,
  author = {Lastname, Firstname},
  title  = {A book entry with sortkey field},
  date = {2000-01-01},
  sortkey = {1}}
@article{itzhaki:phys,
  author = {Itzhaki, Nissan},
  volume = {54},
  number = {2},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. D},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevD.54.1557},
  year = {1996},
  month = {7},
  day = {15},
  title = {Black hole information versus locality},
  pages = {1557--1563}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{ref1,ref2,ref3}
\nocite{knuth:ct,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,itzhaki,itzhaki:phys}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the various ways dates are specified in the example. The `date` field follows the `yyyy-mm-dd` format, but you can omit `-mm-dd` or `-dd`. This field also takes date ranges separated by `/` (e.g. `yyyy/yyyy`, `yyyy-mm-dd/yyyy-mm-dd`, `yyyy/`). By default the beginning of ranges are used for sorting. You can also specify dates with the `year`, `month` and `day` fields. String values for `month` are accepted, but only in 3-letter abbreviations (`jan`, `feb`, `mar`, ...). These must be given without quotes or braces (e.g. `month = jul`).

You can override the chronological order somewhat with the `sortyear` field. In `biblatex-examples.bib`, the `knuth:ct`, `knuth:ct:a` and `knuth:ct:b` entries are given the `sortyear` values `1984-0`, `1984-1` and `1986-1`, respectively.

For descending dates, use the `direction=descending` option setting for `\sort`.

```
\DeclareSortingTemplate{ndymdt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
    \literal{99}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
    \literal{99}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
    \literal{9999}
  }
}
```

[image]

Further details on `\DeclareSortingTemplate` can be found in the biblatex manual.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your adaptions in my minimal example but the first 5 entries are still sorted wrong. :(

Comment: And do you know if it makes a difference to add year/month/day separate in the bib entries or is the date field equivalent?

Comment: Whoops. Sorry about that. Additional fields in each `\sort` group are intended to break ties. I'll make a correction in a minute. You can specify dates any valid way you like - biber will parse the data into the various date fields.

Comment: Audrey is quickly becoming the authoritative source for the Biber-only biblatex features ...