# biblatex – sort by year AND month

Tags: biblatex, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [biblatex sorting by date](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46868/biblatex-sorting-by-date)

I would like to sort my bibliography by year and month in reverse order. For example, a publication from Jan. 2011 should appear after one from Dec. 2011.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46879/10119). It explains how to sort entries by year and month with `biblatex` and biber. You can say `\sort[direction=descending]` for reverse order.

Comment: thanks for the link, I didn't find that.  I am having a hard time with biber (using backend=biber); it gives errors when running bibtex:

I found no \citation commands---while reading file dzpubs.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file dzpubs.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file dzpubs.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Comment: There are already a few questions about how to run biber properly. My first guess would be: did you make sure that your editor properly runs biber instead of bibtex (in TeXshop for instance, it is in Preferences > Engine > Bibtex). Otherwise, it probably won't compile.

Comment: @1yen Don't run bibtex when you're using biber. Run biber _instead_ of bibtex.

Comment: @Audrey Perhaps you can add a hint about `\sort[direction=descending]` in your linked answer, so that we can close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @lockstep Done!