# Anti-chronological bibliography with sorting=ydnt and usage of sortyear

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to get a anti-chronological bibliography, that means I just want to appear the newest items at the top. After reading the the answer for [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46868/biblatex-sorting-by-date) I assumed, that the usage the sorting scheme ydnt and of sortyear (in the format 2012-1, 2012-2 and so on, where 2012-1 is older than 2012-2) should do that.

But it does not, it seems that only the first four digits of sortyear or the entry in year are used (which are in fact the same).

So, why that? And how could I get a new-to-old sorted bibliography without declaring a new sorting scheme? (Doing that I get the desired result.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@MISC{2012_1,
  author = {Me},
  title = {A Oldest, should be below},
  year = {2012},
  sortyear = {2012-1},
}
@MISC{2012_2,
  author = {Me},
  title = {C Second oldest, should be in middle},
  year = {2012},
  sortyear = {2012-2},
}

@MISC{2012_3,
  author = {Me},
  title = {B Newest, should be above},
  year = {2012},
  sortyear = {2012-3},
}
}\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `biblatex` only uses the first four digits for the `sortyear`.  Why?  I assume it's because bibliographies never(?) need to such fine-grained detail.  If I publish two articles in 2012, they only need to be sorted before 2011: no one cares if one was written in March and the other in September. *However*, if I absolutely needed to do this --- say for my own CV and I really want to do it ---, then why not simply use  as sortyears the last four of your digits: `0121; 0122; 0123`? They'll still show up as 2012 when printed....

Comment: Why don't you want to declare a sorting scheme that does what you want? Absent that, you will end up kludging around in the `.bib` file as Jon suggests. That will work, but it's bad practice.

Answer (score 13):

Firstly, note that "2012-1" is not a valid ISO 8601 date format which biblatex expects in the `date` field. It's also not a valid `year` field for obvious reasons. This is why we still have the `month` field. So, to make this work, it's fairly easy. Change the format of your .bib entries to e.g:

```
@MISC{2012_1,
  author = {Me},
  title = {A Oldest, should be below},
  year = {2012},
  month = {1}
}
@MISC{2012_2,
  author = {Me},
  title = {C Second oldest, should be in middle},
  year = {2012},
  month = {2}
}

@MISC{2012_3,
  author = {Me},
  title = {B Newest, should be above},
  year = {2012},
  month = {3}
}
```

and then define a new "year month descending" sorting spec in your preamble. The name is arbitrary but call it say "ymdnt":

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{ymdnt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{sortyear}
    \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{year}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field{month}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
}
```

This is just a copy of the "ydnt" scheme from `biblatex.def` with a sort on the `month` field added after year. Then load biblatex with `sorting=ymdnt` and it all works nicely.

Comment: Thanks for answer, which points me in the right direction. In fact, I just was wondering why the solution in the question linked above works with ynt, but not with ydnt. An the biblatex.def has the answer, because for the ynt sorting scheme there is no restriction to the first four digits (neither for sortyear nor for year), but for the ydnt sorting scheme there is (same as in the code you copied from there).

Comment: How do you define this before `biblatex` is loaded?  Alternatively, how do you pass this option to `biblatex` after it's already loaded?

Comment: Aha, if this goes after `biblatex` is loaded, then `DeclareSortingScheme` apparently doesn't just define the scheme but loads it too.  Might be good to mention this in the answer.