# How to include academic icons like google scholar and research gate in curve CV template

Tags: cv, academicons

I am using a CV template available in overleaf using class `curve`.

In this template `fontawesome` package is working but while using `academicons` it is showing error.

`mwe.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt,british]{curve}
\usepackage{settings}

\ifxetexorluatex 
  \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=5}]{Charis SIL}
  \setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Fira Sans}
  \setmonofont{Inconsolata}
\else 
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[tracking=smallcaps]{microtype}
  \usepackage{fbb}
  \usepackage[type1]{cabin}
  \usepackage[varqu,varl]{zi4}
  \useosf 
\fi
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{own-bib.bib}
\myname{Lim}{Lian\bibnamedelima Tze}
\includecomment{fullonly}
\leftheader{%
  {\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily Lim Lian Tze, Ph.D.}

  \makefield{\faEnvelopeO}{\texttt{liantze@gmail.com}}
  \makefield{\faTwitter}{\texttt{@liantze}}

  \makefield{\faGlobe}{\url{http://liantze.penguinattack.org/}}

  \makefield{\faLinkedinSquare}
  {\url{http://www.linkedin.com/in/limliantze/}}
}
\rightheader{~}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\begin{document}
\makeheaders[c]
\end{document}
```

`settings.sty`:

```
\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningsOff[longtable]
\WarningsOff[array]

\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
  \xetexorluatextrue
\else
  \ifluatex
    \xetexorluatextrue
  \else
    \xetexorluatexfalse
  \fi
\fi

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\RequirePackage[main=british]{babel}
\raggedright

\RequirePackage{fontawesome}

\newcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}}

\RequirePackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot,hmargin=2.25cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{relsize}
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows}

\RequirePackage{comment}
\definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{88AC0B}
\definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{B6073F}

% If you're not a researcher nor an academic, you probably don't need biblatex; delete this line.
\RequirePackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=apa,sorting=ymdnt,uniquename=init,maxnames=7,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

%% Added 17 Jan 2018 from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140641/226 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46879/226
\DeclareSortingScheme{ymdnt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{sortyear}
    \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{year}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
    \literal{00}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
    \literal{00}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
   \node[shape=circle,text=white,fill=MarkerColour!80!black,font=\sffamily\scriptsize\bfseries,inner sep=1pt,text height=1.35ex,minimum width=1.5em,text centered] (char) {#1};}}

\newcounter{bibitem}
\AtBeginBibliography{\setcounter{bibitem}{1}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[2.5em][l]{\circled{\thebibitem}\stepcounter{bibitem}}}

% \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{1.5ex}
\setlength{\bibhang}{2.7em}
\NewBibliographyString{retrieved}
\NewBibliographyString{from}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{british}{
  from = {\textcolor{MarkerColour!80!black}{\faLink}},
  retrieved = {}
}

\headerscale{1}
%\setlength{\headerspace}{6pt}
\rubricfont{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\setlength{\rubricspace}{2pt}
%\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-9pt}
\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-3pt}
\setlength{\subrubricspace}{3pt}
\setlength{\subrubricbeforespace}{4pt}
\def\@@rubrichead#1{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]%\
  \shade[left color=SwishLineColour!60!white, right color=white] rectangle (\@almosttextwidth,2.5pt);
  \node[font={\@rubricfont},inner sep=0pt,text ragged,anchor=south west,text depth=.5ex,text height=1.5ex] at (1pt,2pt) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \vspace\rubricspace%
}

\subrubricfont{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\subrubricalignment{l}

\newcommand{\makefield}[2]{\makebox[1.5em]{\color{MarkerColour!80!black}#1} #2\hspace{2em}}

\keyalignment{r}
\rubricalignment{l}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\urlstyle{tt}

\newcommand{\prefixmarker}[1]{\def\@prefixmarker{#1}}
\def\@prefixmarker{\relscale{.9}\faBookmark}

\prefix{%
  \hspace*{-1ex}
  \color{MarkerColour!80!black}\@prefixmarker%
  \hspace*{1ex}%
}

\newcommand{\makerubrichead}[1]{\vskip\baselineskip\@@rubrichead{#1}}

\defbibheading{subbibliography}{\vskip\subrubricbeforespace{\@subrubricfont\hspace{3pt}#1}\par}

\defbibfilter{booksandchapters}{%
( type=book or type=incollection )
}

\newcommand{\myname}[2]{%
   \def\@mylastname{#1}%
   \def\@myfirstname{#2}%
}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\@mylastname}}
               and
               test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\@myfirstname}}}
    {\textbf{#1}}%
    {#1}%
}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\@mylastname}}
               and
               test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\@myfirstname}}}
    {\textbf{#1}}%
    {#1}%
}

\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=black,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Please don't provide external links. Add a minimal working example here instead.

Comment: Where is `settings.sty`?

Comment: How to attach the settings.sty

Comment: It is only a TeX code. Add it like a normal code.

Answer (score 13):

Well, usually you have to add `\usepackage{academicons}` to be able to use [academicons](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/academicons). (BTW: Using `academicons` means you have to compile with `lualatex` or `xelatex`.)

Then you can access the several icons with for example:

```
DOI: \aiDoi  % <========================================================
Googlescholar: \aiGoogleScholar
ResearchGate: \aiResearchGate % <=======================================
```

or with

```
\makefield{\aiGoogleScholar}{\url{http://liantze.penguinattack.org/}}
%          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

in a field of personal informations.

If that also works in overleaf I can not say, I have no experience with that online compiler. Please test it yourself.

With your given `settings.sty` and the following cv code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt,british]{curve}

\usepackage{settings} % <======================================

\ifxetexorluatex 
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  %\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=5}]{Charis SIL}
  %\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Fira Sans}
  %\setmonofont{Inconsolata}
\else 
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[tracking=smallcaps]{microtype}
  \usepackage{fbb}
  \usepackage[type1]{cabin}
  \usepackage[varqu,varl]{zi4}
  \useosf 
\fi

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{academicons} % <============================================
\addbibresource{own-bib.bib}

\myname{Lim}{Lian\bibnamedelima Tze}
\includecomment{fullonly}
\leftheader{%
  {\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily Lim Lian Tze, Ph.D.}

  \makefield{\faEnvelopeO}{\texttt{liantze@gmail.com}}
  \makefield{\faTwitter}{\texttt{@liantze}}

  \makefield{\aiGoogleScholar}{\url{http://liantze.penguinattack.org/}} % \faGlobe
  %          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  \makefield{\faLinkedinSquare}
  {\url{http://www.linkedin.com/in/limliantze/}}
}
\rightheader{~}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}


\begin{document}
\makeheaders[c]

DOI: \aiDoi  % <========================================================
Googlescholar: \aiGoogleScholar
ResearchGate: \aiResearchGate % <=======================================

\end{document}
```

I get with current MiKTeX 2.9 the following result:

[image]

compiled with `lualatex`. Please see that I commented your used font because I have not installed on my system.

Comment: I can confirm this works in overleaf

Comment: In Overleaf, had to change compiler to XeLaTeX (from Menu), then it worked!