# Itemize instead of enumerate in CurVe CV

Tags: enumerate, itemize

I'm editing this costumized CurVe CV: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-customised-curve-cv/mvmbhkwsnmwv

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This CV example/template is based on my own
% CV which I (lamely attempted) to clean up, so that
% it's less of an eyesore and easier for others to use.
%
% LianTze Lim (liantze@gmail.com)
% 16 September, 2016
%
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt,british]{curve}

% Uncomment to enable Chinese; needs XeLaTeX
% \usepackage{ctex}

\usepackage{settings}

% Change the fonts if you want
\ifxetexorluatex % If you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont[SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=5},Numbers=OldStyle]{EB Garamond}
  \setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX,BoldFont=Fira Sans Medium]{Fira Sans}
  \setmonofont{Inconsolata}
\else % If you're using pdfLaTeX or latex
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[tracking=smallcaps]{microtype}
  \usepackage{ebgaramond}
  \usepackage[type1]{cabin}
  \usepackage[varqu,varl]{zi4}
\fi
\usepackage{csquotes}

%% Only needed if you want a Publication List
\addbibresource{own-bib.bib}

%% Specify your last name and first name (as given in the .bib) to automatically bold your own name in the publications list. One caveat: You need to write \bibnamedelima where there's a space in your name for this to work properly for now...
\myname{Lim}{Lian\bibnamedelima Tze}
% \myname{d'Andrimont}{Raphaël}

% Change the page margins if you want
% \geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

% Change the colours if you want
% \definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{00FFFF}
% \definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{0000CC}

% Change the item prefix marker if you want
% \prefixmarker{$\diamond$}

%% Photo is only shown if "fullonly" is included
\includecomment{fullonly}
% \excludecomment{fullonly}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\leftheader{%
  {\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily Lim Lian Tze, Ph.D.}

  \makefield{\faEnvelopeO}{\texttt{liantze@gmail.com}}
  \makefield{\faTwitter}{\texttt{@liantze}}

  \makefield{\faGlobe}{\url{http://liantze.penguinattack.org/}}

  \makefield{\faLinkedinSquare}
  {\url{http://www.linkedin.com/in/limliantze/}}
}

\rightheader{~}
\begin{fullonly}
\photo[r]{photo}
\photoscale{0.13}
\end{fullonly}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}

\begin{document}
\makeheaders[c]

\makerubric{employment}
\makerubric{education}

% If you're not a researcher nor an academic, you probably don't have any publications; delete this line.
%% Sometimes when a section can't be nicely modelled with the \entry[]... mechanism; hack our own and use \input NOT \makerubric
\input{publications}

\makerubric{skills}
\makerubric{misc}

\makerubric{referee}
% \input{referee-full}

\end{document}
```

In the publications list, how can I get rid of the numbers and just keep the bullets?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable: the file `settings.sty` is not available. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: [`filecontents`](https://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents?lang=en) may be helpful ;)

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can patch lines 78-80 of file `settings.sty` as follows:

```
\newcounter{bibitem}
\AtBeginBibliography{\setcounter{bibitem}{1}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[2.5em][l]{\circled{\thebibitem}\stepcounter{bibitem}}}
```

become

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[2.5em][l]{\circled{}}}
```

In fact you do no longer need the `bibitem`counter.

The MWE is as follows (the parts not related to the publications are commented out)

```
\begin{filecontents}{publications.tex}
    %% Sometimes when a section can't be nicely modelled with the \entry[]... mechanism; hack our own
    \makerubrichead{Research Publications}

    %% Assuming you've already given \addbibresource{own-bib.bib} in the main doc. Right? Right???
    \nocite{*}

    %% If you just want everything in one list
    % \printbibliography[heading={none}]

    \printbibliography[heading={subbibliography},title={Journal Articles},type=article]

    \printbibliography[heading={subbibliography},title={Conference Proceedings},type=inproceedings]

    \printbibliography[heading={subbibliography},title={Books and Chapters},filter={booksandchapters}]

    % \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{own-bib.bib}
    @article{lim:etal:kdtei:2016,
     title = {Digitising a machine-tractable version of {K}amus {D}ewan with \textsc{tei-p5}},
     author = {Lim, Lian Tze and Chiew, Ruoh Tau and Tang, Enya Kong and Rusli, Abdul Ghani and Naimah, Yusof},
     year = {2016},
     keywords = {Machine-tractable dictionaries, TEI, Language resources, Bahasa Malaysia},
     volume = {4},
     pages = {e2205v1},
     journal = {PeerJ Preprints},
     issn = {2167-9843},
     url = {https://doi.org/10.7287/peerj.preprints.2205v1},
     doi = {10.7287/peerj.preprints.2205v1},
    }

    @INPROCEEDINGS{Boon:Lim:ICEEE2014,
    author={Boon, Kah Ming and Lim, Lian Tze},
    year={2014},
    booktitle={Proceedings of the 3rd {I}nternational {C}onference on {E}-{L}earning and {E}-{T}echnologies in {E}ducation (\textsc{iceee} 2014)},
    title={An Examination Question Paper Preparation System with Content-Style Separation and {B}loom's Taxonomy Categorisation},
    address={Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia},
    pages={39--47},
    url={http://goo.gl/pfdUfm}
    }

    @PHDTHESIS{Lim:thesis:2013,
      author = {Lim, Lian Tze},
      title = {Low-Cost Multilingual Lexicon Construction for Under-Resourced Languages},
      school = {Faculty of Computing and Informatics, Multimedia University},
      year = {2013},
      address = {Cyberjaya, Malaysia}
    }

    @MASTERSTHESIS{lim:2006:thesis,
      author = {Lim, Lian Tze},
      title = {Improving Translation Selection with Conceptual Vectors},
      school = {School of Computer Sciences, Universiti Sains Malaysia},
      year = {2006},
      type = {MSc thesis},
      address = {Penang, Malaysia},
      booktitle = {Proceedings of the {R}egional {C}omputer {S}cience {P}ostgraduate
        {C}olloquium ({R}e\textsc{cspc}'06)},
      keywords = {own},
      owner = {liantze},
      timestamp = {2006.11.12}
    }

    @INCOLLECTION{Tang:etal:Blexisma2:2009,
      author = {Tang, Enya Kong and Lim, Lian Tze and Ye, Hong Hoe and Didier Schwab},
      title = {Grid-enabled {B}lexisma2},
      booktitle = {Grid Computing Cluster: The Development and Integration of Grid Applications
        and Services},
      publisher = {Platform for Information \& Communication Technology Research, Universiti
        Sains Malaysia},
      year = {2009},
      editor = {Bahari Belaton and Lim, Lian Tze},
      pages = {23--26},
      address = {Penang, Malaysia},
      keywords = {own},
      owner = {liantzelim},
      timestamp = {2009.07.03}
    }

    @BOOK{Bahari:Lim:2009,
      title = {Grid Computing Cluster: The Development and Integration of Grid Services
        and Applications},
      publisher = {Platform for Information \& Communication Technology Research, Universiti
        Sains Malaysia},
      year = {2009},
      editor = {Bahari Belaton and Lim, Lian Tze},
      address = {Penang, Malaysia},
      isbn = {978-983-3986-58-3},
      keywords = {own},
      owner = {liantzelim},
      timestamp = {2009.06.27}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{settings.sty}
    \RequirePackage{silence}
    \WarningsOff[longtable]
    \WarningsOff[array]

    \usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
    \newif\ifxetexorluatex
    \ifxetex
      \xetexorluatextrue
    \else
      \ifluatex
        \xetexorluatextrue
      \else
        \xetexorluatexfalse
      \fi
    \fi

    \RequirePackage{graphicx}
    \RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
    \RequirePackage[main=british]{babel}
    \raggedright

    \RequirePackage{fontawesome}

    \newcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}}

    \RequirePackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot,hmargin=2.25cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
    \RequirePackage{relsize}
    \RequirePackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
    \RequirePackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows}

    \RequirePackage{comment}
    \definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{88AC0B}
    \definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{B6073F}

    % If you're not a researcher nor an academic, you probably don't need biblatex; delete this line.
    \RequirePackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=apa,sorting=ymdnt,uniquename=init,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
    \DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
    %% Added 17 Jan 2018 from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140641/226 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46879/226
    \DeclareSortingTemplate{ymdnt}{
      \sort{
        \field{presort}
      }
      \sort[final]{
        \field{sortkey}
      }
      \sort[direction=descending]{
        \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{sortyear}
        \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{year}
        \literal{9999}
      }
      \sort[direction=descending]{
        \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
        \literal{00}
      }
      \sort[direction=descending]{
        \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
        \literal{00}
      }
      \sort{
        \field{sortname}
        \field{author}
        \field{editor}
        \field{translator}
        \field{sorttitle}
        \field{title}
      }
      \sort{
        \field{sorttitle}
        \field{title}
      }
    }

    \RequirePackage{tikz}
    \newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
       \node[shape=circle,text=white,fill=MarkerColour!80!black,font=\sffamily\scriptsize\bfseries,inner sep=1pt,text height=1.35ex,minimum width=1.5em,text centered] (char) {#1};}}

    % \newcounter{bibitem}
    % \AtBeginBibliography{\setcounter{bibitem}{1}}
    % \AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[2.5em][l]{\circled{\thebibitem}\stepcounter{bibitem}}}
    \AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[2.5em][l]{\circled{}}}

    % \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}
    \setlength{\bibitemsep}{1.5ex}
    \setlength{\bibhang}{2.7em}
    \NewBibliographyString{retrieved}
    \NewBibliographyString{from}
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{british}{
      from = {\textcolor{MarkerColour!80!black}{\faLink}},
      retrieved = {}
    }

    \headerscale{1}
    %\setlength{\headerspace}{6pt}
    \rubricfont{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
    \setlength{\rubricspace}{2pt}
    %\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-9pt}
    \setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-3pt}
    \setlength{\subrubricspace}{3pt}
    \setlength{\subrubricbeforespace}{4pt}
    \def\@@rubrichead#1{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]%\
      \shade[left color=SwishLineColour!60!white, right color=white] rectangle (\@almosttextwidth,2.5pt);
      \node[font={\@rubricfont},inner sep=0pt,text ragged,anchor=south west,text depth=.5ex,text height=1.5ex] at (1pt,2pt) {#1};
      \end{tikzpicture}%
      \vspace\rubricspace%
    }

    \subrubricfont{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
    \subrubricalignment{l}

    \newcommand{\makefield}[2]{\makebox[1.5em]{\color{MarkerColour!80!black}#1} #2\hspace{2em}}

    \keyalignment{r}
    \rubricalignment{l}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
    \urlstyle{tt}

    \newcommand{\prefixmarker}[1]{\def\@prefixmarker{#1}}
    \def\@prefixmarker{\relscale{.9}\faBookmark}

    \prefix{%
      \hspace*{-1ex}
      \color{MarkerColour!80!black}\@prefixmarker%
      \hspace*{1ex}%
    }

    \newcommand{\makerubrichead}[1]{\vskip\baselineskip\@@rubrichead{#1}}

    \defbibheading{subbibliography}{\vskip\subrubricbeforespace{\@subrubricfont\hspace{3pt}#1}\par}

    \defbibfilter{booksandchapters}{%
    ( type=book or type=incollection )
    }

    \newcommand{\myname}[2]{%
       \def\@mylastname{#1}%
       \def\@myfirstname{#2}%
    }

    \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
      \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\@mylastname}}
                   and
                   test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\@myfirstname}}}
        {\textbf{#1}}%
        {#1}%
    }

    \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
      \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\@mylastname}}
                   and
                   test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\@myfirstname}}}
        {\textbf{#1}}%
        {#1}%
    }

    \RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=black,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt,british]{curve}

% Uncomment to enable Chinese; needs XeLaTeX
% \usepackage{ctex}

\usepackage{settings}

% Change the fonts if you want
\ifxetexorluatex % If you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont[SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=5},Numbers=OldStyle]{EB Garamond}
  \setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX,BoldFont=Fira Sans Medium]{Fira Sans}
  \setmonofont{Inconsolata}
\else % If you're using pdfLaTeX or latex
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[tracking=smallcaps]{microtype}
  \usepackage{ebgaramond}
  \usepackage[type1]{cabin}
  \usepackage[varqu,varl]{zi4}
\fi
\usepackage{csquotes}

%% Only needed if you want a Publication List
\addbibresource{own-bib.bib}

%% Specify your last name and first name (as given in the .bib) to automatically bold your own name in the publications list. One caveat: You need to write \bibnamedelima where there's a space in your name for this to work properly for now...
\myname{Lim}{Lian\bibnamedelima Tze}
% \myname{d'Andrimont}{Raphaël}

% Change the page margins if you want
% \geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

% Change the colours if you want
% \definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{00FFFF}
% \definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{0000CC}

% Change the item prefix marker if you want
% \prefixmarker{$\diamond$}

%% Photo is only shown if "fullonly" is included
\includecomment{fullonly}
% \excludecomment{fullonly}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\leftheader{%
  {\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily Lim Lian Tze, Ph.D.}

  \makefield{\faEnvelopeO}{\texttt{liantze@gmail.com}}
  \makefield{\faTwitter}{\texttt{@liantze}}

  \makefield{\faGlobe}{\url{http://liantze.penguinattack.org/}}

  \makefield{\faLinkedinSquare}
  {\url{http://www.linkedin.com/in/limliantze/}}
}

\rightheader{~}
\begin{fullonly}
\photo[r]{photo}
\photoscale{0.13}
\end{fullonly}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}

\begin{document}
% \makeheaders[c]

% \makerubric{employment}
% \makerubric{education}

% If you're not a researcher nor an academic, you probably don't have any publications; delete this line.
%% Sometimes when a section can't be nicely modelled with the \entry[]... mechanism; hack our own and use \input NOT \makerubric
\input{publications}

% \makerubric{skills}
% \makerubric{misc}

% \makerubric{referee}
% % \input{referee-full}

\end{document}
```

[image]