# Curve `\text` option to insert plain text in the middle of a rubric

Tags: curve-class

I'm trying to use `curve` class to insert plain text in the middle of a rubric, without fancy key/prefix formatting.

As the manual reads in page 9 here:
https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/curve/curve.pdf

It seems it is as simple as using the `\text` option (optionally also combined with `\par`).

Well, this seems to span lines across and out of the document:

[image]

`brief_description.tex`:

```
\begin{rubric}{Brief Description}

\text{\par
This is a brief summary about the experience on several fields and professional interests based on the studies and long trajectory in several aspects and . . .\par}                                              


\end{rubric}
```

`document.tex` (this is the document to compile)

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt,british]{curve}                                                  

\usepackage{settings}

% Change the fonts if you want
\ifxetexorluatex % If you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=5}]{Charis SIL}
  \setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Lato}
  \setmonofont{Inconsolata}
\else % If you're using pdfLaTeX or latex
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[tracking=smallcaps]{microtype}
  \usepackage{fbb}
  \usepackage[type1]{cabin}
  \usepackage[varqu,varl]{zi4}
  \useosf  %% Comment out if you prefer lining figures rather than old style figures
\fi
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{academicons}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\myname{abc}{def}
\includecomment{fullonly}

\usepackage{marvosym} % For cool symbols.
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{multicol}


\title{Curriculum Vitae}


\begin{document}%\layout

\makerubric{brief_description}


\end{document}
```

`settings.sty`:

```
\RequirePackage{silence}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
\WarningsOff[longtable]
\WarningsOff[array]

\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
  \xetexorluatextrue
\else
  \ifluatex
    \xetexorluatextrue
  \else
    \xetexorluatexfalse
  \fi 
\fi

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\RequirePackage[main=british]{babel}
\raggedright

\RequirePackage{fontawesome}

\newcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}}

% \RequirePackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot,hmargin=2.25cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage{relsize}
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows}

\RequirePackage{comment}
\definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{88AC0B}
\definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{B6073F}

\RequirePackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=ieee,dashed=false,uniquename=init,sorting=ydnt,maxnames=100,maxbibnames=99,defernumbers=true]{biblatex} % for vil exp application
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

%% Added 17 Jan 2018 from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140641/226 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46879/226
\DeclareSortingScheme{ymdnt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{sortyear}
    \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{year}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
    \literal{00}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
    \literal{00}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
   \node[shape=circle,text=white,fill=MarkerColour!80!black,font=\sffamily\scriptsize\bfseries,inner sep=1pt,text height=1.35ex,minimum width=1.5em,text centered] (char) {#1};}}
   
\newcounter{bibitem}
\AtBeginBibliography{\setcounter{bibitem}{1}}
%\AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[2.5em][l]{\circled{\thebibitem}\stepcounter{bibitem}}} % commented in order to remove the red circles 1, 2, 3 . . . in References. For vil exp.
% \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{1.5ex}
\setlength{\bibhang}{2.7em}
\NewBibliographyString{retrieved}
\NewBibliographyString{from}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{british}{
  from = {\textcolor{MarkerColour!80!black}{\faLink}},
  retrieved = {}
}

\headerscale{1}
%\setlength{\headerspace}{6pt}
\rubricfont{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\setlength{\rubricspace}{2pt}
%\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-9pt}
\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-3pt}
\setlength{\subrubricspace}{3pt}
\setlength{\subrubricbeforespace}{4pt}
\def\@@rubrichead#1{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]%\
  \shade[left color=SwishLineColour!60!white, right color=white] rectangle (\@almosttextwidth,2.5pt);
  \node[font={\@rubricfont},inner sep=0pt,text ragged,anchor=south west,text depth=.5ex,text height=1.5ex] at (1pt,2pt) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \vspace\rubricspace%
}

\subrubricfont{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\subrubricalignment{l}

\newcommand{\makefield}[2]{\makebox[1.5em]{\color{MarkerColour!80!black}#1} #2\hspace{2em}}

\keyalignment{r}
\rubricalignment{l}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\urlstyle{tt}

\newcommand{\prefixmarker}[1]{\def\@prefixmarker{#1}}
% The following line controls the size of the \item :
%\def\@prefixmarker{\relscale{.9}\faBookmark} % default.
\def\@prefixmarker{\relscale{.6}\faBookmark}

\prefix{%
  \hspace*{-1ex}
  \color{MarkerColour!80!black}\@prefixmarker%
  \hspace*{1ex}%
}

\newcommand{\makerubrichead}[1]{\vskip\baselineskip\@@rubrichead{#1}}

\defbibheading{subbibliography}{\vskip\subrubricbeforespace{\@subrubricfont\hspace{3pt}#1}\par}

\defbibfilter{booksandchapters}{%
( type=book or type=incollection )
}

\newcommand{\myname}[2]{%
   \def\@mylastname{#1}%
   \def\@myfirstname{#2}%
}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\@mylastname}}
               and 
               test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\@myfirstname}}}
    {\textbf{#1}}%
    {#1}%
}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\@mylastname}}
               and 
               test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\@myfirstname}}}
    {\textbf{#1}}%
    {#1}%
}

%----------------  This controls the hreference to links:
%\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=black,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,filecolor=black,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=red,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `settings.sty` loads many packages, with `hyperref` the last as it should be. (`csquotes` could be an exception)

So add all new packages before `\usepackage{settings}`, checking if a new package does not conflicts with others or the class.

In this case removing  `\usepackage{amsmath}` solves the issue.

[image: a]

Your preamble should start as

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\listfiles
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt,british]{curve}  
                                                
\usepackage{academicons}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{marvosym} % For cool symbols.
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{settings} % last <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 ....
```

Comment: Many thanks, @Simon Dispa