# How to change the symbol of the enumeration, CV Curve

Tags: symbols, cv, curve-class, customize

I'm editing this costumized CurVe CV: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-customised-curve-cv/mvmbhkwsnmwv .

I want to put the symbol \faBook instead of \faBookmark in the section Education, but I want that the symbol \faBookmark to remain in the others sections: Employment History ecc...

This is the settings.sty :

```
\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningsOff[longtable]
\WarningsOff[array]

\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
  \xetexorluatextrue
\else
  \ifluatex
    \xetexorluatextrue
  \else
    \xetexorluatexfalse
  \fi
\fi

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\RequirePackage{babel}
\raggedright

\RequirePackage[fixed]{fontawesome5}

\newcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}}

\RequirePackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot,hmargin=2.25cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{relsize}
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows}

\RequirePackage{comment}
\definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{88AC0B}
\definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{B6073F}

% If you're not a researcher nor an academic, you probably don't need biblatex; delete this line.
\RequirePackage[bibstyle=apa6,sorting=ymdnt,uniquename=init,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\RequirePackage{csquotes}
%% Added 17 Jan 2018 from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140641/226 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46879/226
\DeclareSortingTemplate{ymdnt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{sortyear}
    \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{year}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
    \literal{00}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
    \literal{00}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
   \node[shape=circle,text=white,fill=MarkerColour!80!black,font=\sffamily\scriptsize\bfseries,inner sep=1pt,text height=1.35ex,minimum width=1.5em,text centered] (char) {#1};}}
   
\newcounter{bibitem}
\AtBeginBibliography{\setcounter{bibitem}{1}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[2.5em][l]{\circled{\thebibitem}\stepcounter{bibitem}}}

% \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{1.5ex}
\setlength{\bibhang}{2.5em}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\xpretofieldformat{doi}
  {\textcolor{MarkerColour!80!black}{\scriptsize\faLink}}
  {}{}
\xpretofieldformat{url}
  {\textcolor{MarkerColour!80!black}{\scriptsize\faLink}}
  {}{}

\headerscale{1}
%\setlength{\headerspace}{6pt}
\rubricfont{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\setlength{\rubricspace}{2pt}
%\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-9pt}
\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-3pt}
\setlength{\subrubricspace}{3pt}
\setlength{\subrubricbeforespace}{4pt}
\def\@@rubrichead#1{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]%\
  \shade[left color=SwishLineColour!60!white, right color=white] rectangle (\@almosttextwidth,2.5pt);
  \node[font={\@rubricfont},inner sep=0pt,text ragged,anchor=south west,text depth=.5ex,text height=1.5ex] at (1pt,2pt) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \vspace\rubricspace%
}

\subrubricfont{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\subrubricalignment{l}

\newcommand{\makefield}[2]{\makebox[1.5em]{\color{MarkerColour!80!black}#1} #2\hspace{2em}}

\keyalignment{r}
\rubricalignment{l}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\urlstyle{tt}

\newcommand{\prefixmarker}[1]{\def\@prefixmarker{#1}}
\def\@prefixmarker{\relscale{.9}\faBookmark}

\prefix{%
  \hspace*{-1ex}
  \color{MarkerColour!80!black}\@prefixmarker%
  \hspace*{1ex}%
}

\newcommand{\makerubrichead}[1]{\vskip\baselineskip\@@rubrichead{#1}}

\defbibheading{subbibliography}{\vskip\subrubricbeforespace{\@subrubricfont\hspace{3pt}#1}\par}

\defbibfilter{booksandchapters}{%
( type=book or type=incollection )
}

\newcommand{\myname}[2]{%
   \def\@mylastname{#1}%
   \def\@myfirstname{#2}%
}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\@mylastname}}
               and
               test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\@myfirstname}}}
    {\textbf{#1}}%
    {#1}%
}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\@mylastname}}
               and
               test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\@myfirstname}}}
    {\textbf{#1}}%
    {#1}%
}

\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=black,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1)** Add this code before `\begin{document}`

```
\makeatletter   
\newcommand\entryx[1][]{%
    \@nextentry%
    \bgroup\gdef\@beforespace{\subrubricbeforespace}%
    \gdef\@nextentry{\\\par}\@key{#1}%
    \egroup% 
    \@@key&\hspace*{-2ex}\color{MarkerColour!80!black}\relscale{.8}\faBook\hspace*{1.5ex}&}
\makeatother
```

**(2)** Use `\entryx` when loading Education entries:

```
\begin{rubric}{Education}

\entryx[2009 -- 2013]%
    \textbf{Ph.D., Unseen University} High Energy Magic.
    \par Thesis title: \emph{Low-Cost Mana Generation in Under-Resourced Environments.}
%
\entryx[2003 -- 2006]%
    \textbf{M.Sc.~Computer Science, Unseen} in High Energy Magic.\par
    Thesis title: \emph{Applying ant algorithms in automatic design of novel magic charms}.
\end{rubric}
```

[image: b]