# Generate list of references from bib file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cross-referencing

I have a .bib file containing about 100+ publications references. I want to generate the pdf file with all the references in descending order of publication year, just as it appears in journals?

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Welcome to TeX.SX! You can use `\nocite{*}` to include all your entries from the bibfile and then create the bibliography as usual.

Answer (score 1):

With `biblatex` this is easily possible. You basically only need two ingredients.

1. `sorting=ydnt` in the `biblatex` package options will sort your bibliography descending by year of publication. More `sorting` options are at [Biblatex citation order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51434/35864). For a more fine-grained sorting see [biblatex sorting by date](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46868/35864).
2. `\nocite{*}` in your document will just add all entries in your `.bib` file to the bibliography without them having to be cited explicitly. See [Using BibTeX to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/35864).

Now

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, sorting=ydnt, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

produces a six-page document containing all works in `biblatex-examples.bib` in reverse chronological order.

For example parts of page 2 of the resulting PDF read

[image: snippet from page 2]

---

The style [`biblatex-publist`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-publist) is a dedicated style for lists of publications

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[bibstyle=publist, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{worman,sigfridsson,geer,nussbaum,cicero}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: publist bibliography]