# Sorting references of the same author of the same year ascending

Tags: bibliographies, biber, sorting, biblatex-chicago

I am citing three newspaper articles from the same author, they were issued in three consecutive days (October 23rd 2010 - October 25th 2010). Using Biblatex Chicago (authordate) they are sorted in descending order as the latest article (of October 25th) have the suffix "a" after the year and the first article (of October 23rd) have the suffix "c". How can I sort them in ascending order, so that they the article of October 23rd has the suffix a and not c-

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate, isbn=false,doi=false,ibidtracker=false]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{jobname.bib}
@article{al-bisriAlIdaraAlkanasiyaBain2010,
  title = {Al-{{Idāra}} al-Kanasiya Bain Niẓām al-Milla Wa-l-Ǧamāʿa al-Waṭanīya (3)},
  author = {Al-Bišrī, Ṭāriq},
  date = {2010-10-25},
  journaltitle = {Aš-Šurūq al-ǧadīd},
  location = {{Kairo}},
  entrysubtype = {newspaper}
}

@article{al-bisriAlIdaraAlkanasiyaBaina2010,
  title = {Al-{{Idāra}} al-Kanasiya Baina Niẓām al-Milla Wa-l-Ǧamāʿa al-Waṭaniyya (2)},
  author = {Al-Bišrī, Ṭāriq},
  date = {2010-10-24},
  journaltitle = {Aš-Šurūq al-ǧadīd},
  location = {{Kairo}},
  entrysubtype = {newspaper}
}

@article{al-bisriAlIdaraAlkanasiyaBainaa2010,
  title = {Al-{{Idāra}} al-Kanasiya Bainaa Niẓām al-Milla Wa-l-Ǧamāʿa al-Waṭaniyya (1)},
  author = {Al-Bišrī, Ṭāriq},
  date = {2010-10-23},
  journaltitle = {Aš-Šurūq al-ǧadīd},
  location = {{Kairo}},
  entrysubtype = {newspaper}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\blindtext \autocite[Vgl][13]{al-bisriAlIdaraAlkanasiyaBain2010}

\blindtext \autocite[Vgl][13]{al-bisriAlIdaraAlkanasiyaBaina2010}

\blindtext \autocite[Vgl][13]{al-bisriAlIdaraAlkanasiyaBainaa2010}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**The output** 
[image]

Comment: Can you add the a b c letters yourself?  Because it looks like in the present ordering, while perhaps not by date, they are in alphabetical order: Bain --> Baina --> Bainaa.

Comment: You mean changing the citation key?

Comment: You must keep the citation keys unique. But the `title` fields contain `Bain`, `Baina`, and `Bainaa` -- is this intended?

Comment: @Mico I have copied them from Zotero using Better biblatex, apparently it was changed there

Comment: I have tried it, but it didn't work. @Polyhat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `biblatex-chicago`'s `authordate` style sorts by name, year and title. Even if you give a full date, only the year is used for sorting. That means that the entries from the question are sorted solely by their title fields (because `author` and `year` are the same).

This can be changed by modifying the sorting template to include sorting for `month` and `day` as follows (cf. [biblatex sorting by date](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46868/35864))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate, isbn=false,doi=false,ibidtracker=false]{biblatex-chicago}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{cms}{% Updated to >3.7 format
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{namea}
    \field{editor}
    \field{nameb}
    \field{translator}
    \field{namec}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{journaltitle}
    \field{organization}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{labelyear}
    \field{year}
    \field{origyear}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{month}
    \field{origmonth}
    \literal{00}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{day}
    \field{origday}
    \literal{00}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{endyear}
    \field{eventendyear}
    \field{origendyear}
  }
  \sort{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
    \literal{0000}
  }
}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{al-bisriAlIdaraAlkanasiyaBain2010,
  title        = {Al-{{Idāra}} al-Kanasiya Bain Niẓām al-Milla Wa-l-Ǧamāʿa al-Waṭanīya (3)},
  author       = {Al-Bišrī, Ṭāriq},
  date         = {2010-10-25},
  journaltitle = {Aš-Šurūq al-ǧadīd},
  location     = {Kairo},
  entrysubtype = {newspaper},
}
@article{al-bisriAlIdaraAlkanasiyaBaina2010,
  title        = {Al-{{Idāra}} al-Kanasiya Baina Niẓām al-Milla Wa-l-Ǧamāʿa al-Waṭaniyya (2)},
  author       = {Al-Bišrī, Ṭāriq},
  date         = {2010-10-24},
  journaltitle = {Aš-Šurūq al-ǧadīd},
  location     = {Kairo},
  entrysubtype = {newspaper},
}
@article{al-bisriAlIdaraAlkanasiyaBainaa2010,
  title        = {Al-{{Idāra}} al-Kanasiya Bainaa Niẓām al-Milla Wa-l-Ǧamāʿa al-Waṭaniyya (1)},
  author       = {Al-Bišrī, Ṭāriq},
  date         = {2010-10-23},
  journaltitle = {Aš-Šurūq al-ǧadīd},
  location     = {Kairo},
  entrysubtype = {newspaper},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[Vgl.][13]{al-bisriAlIdaraAlkanasiyaBain2010}

ipsum \autocite[Vgl.][13]{al-bisriAlIdaraAlkanasiyaBaina2010}

dolor \autocite[Vgl.][13]{al-bisriAlIdaraAlkanasiyaBainaa2010}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography in the expected sorting.]

---

Alternatively, you can use `sorttitle` to manually force a different sorting order when the title is considered. For example

```
@article{al-bisriAlIdaraAlkanasiyaBain2010,
  title        = {Al-{{Idāra}} al-Kanasiya Bain Niẓām al-Milla Wa-l-Ǧamāʿa al-Waṭanīya (3)},
  sorttitle    = {Aš-Šurūq al-ǧadīd 2010-10-25},
  author       = {Al-Bišrī, Ṭāriq},
  date         = {2010-10-25},
  journaltitle = {Aš-Šurūq al-ǧadīd},
  location     = {Kairo},
  entrysubtype = {newspaper},
}
@article{al-bisriAlIdaraAlkanasiyaBaina2010,
  title        = {Al-{{Idāra}} al-Kanasiya Baina Niẓām al-Milla Wa-l-Ǧamāʿa al-Waṭaniyya (2)},
  sorttitle    = {Aš-Šurūq al-ǧadīd 2010-10-24},
  author       = {Al-Bišrī, Ṭāriq},
  date         = {2010-10-24},
  journaltitle = {Aš-Šurūq al-ǧadīd},
  location     = {Kairo},
  entrysubtype = {newspaper},
}
@article{al-bisriAlIdaraAlkanasiyaBainaa2010,
  title        = {Al-{{Idāra}} al-Kanasiya Bainaa Niẓām al-Milla Wa-l-Ǧamāʿa al-Waṭaniyya (1)},
  sorttitle    = {Aš-Šurūq al-ǧadīd 2010-10-23},
  author       = {Al-Bišrī, Ṭāriq},
  date         = {2010-10-23},
  journaltitle = {Aš-Šurūq al-ǧadīd},
  location     = {Kairo},
  entrysubtype = {newspaper},
}
```