# How to modify apalike.bst to sort references chronologically?

Tags: bibtex, apa-style, sorting

I want to sort chronologically a list of references using the `apalike.bst` style, since this order seems more natural for showing in a CV. I tried to follow the approach outlined in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33332/56546 but without success (I really do not understand too much about `.bst` syntax). Any help on how to conveniently hack `apalike.bst` to do the job?

PS. I know that I can perform this switching to the `biblatex` package, but for the moment I would like to solve the problem without it, since I am using `multibib`.

EDIT: The kind of sorting I am looking for is: 1) by year of publication; 2) by alphabetical order of the author's surnames. I do not care about sorting by month after year in 1), but it is OK.

Comment: By chronological ordering, do you mean sorting the bibliographic items by year and month, or sorting the way the items are cited in the body of the document?

Comment: @Mico I mean sorting by year (I do not care about month, but it is OK). I edit the question to incorporate this clarification.

Answer (score 3):

I modified the `apalike.bst` entry for `bib.sort.order` and merely swapped `sort.label` (which had been first) with `year field.or.null sortify`, to read as

```
FUNCTION {bib.sort.order}
{ year field.or.null sortify
  "    "
  *
  sort.label
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}
```

Thus, with the following MWE,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{junk.bib}
@ARTICLE{bake67,
        TITLE   = "Prediction and scaling of reflected impulse from
                        strong blast waves",
        AUTHOR  = "Baker, W. E.",
        JOURNAL = "International Journal of Mechanical Sciences",
        VOLUME  = "9",
        NUMBER  = "1",
        PAGES   = "45--51",
        YEAR    = "1967"                        }
@ARTICLE{Acme72,
        TITLE   = "Prediction and scaling of reflected impulse from
                        strong blast waves",
        AUTHOR  = "Acme, W. E.",
        JOURNAL = "International Journal of Mechanical Sciences",
        VOLUME  = "9",
        NUMBER  = "1",
        PAGES   = "45--51",
        YEAR    = "1972"                        }
@ARTICLE{cake71,
        TITLE   = "Prediction and scaling of reflected impulse from
                        strong blast waves",
        AUTHOR  = "Cake, W. E.",
        JOURNAL = "International Journal of Mechanical Sciences",
        VOLUME  = "9",
        NUMBER  = "1",
        PAGES   = "45--51",
        YEAR    = "1971"                        }
@ARTICLE{Delta71,
        TITLE   = "Prediction and scaling of reflected impulse from
                        strong blast waves",
        AUTHOR  = "Delta, W. E.",
        JOURNAL = "International Journal of Mechanical Sciences",
        VOLUME  = "9",
        NUMBER  = "1",
        PAGES   = "45--51",
        YEAR    = "1971"                        }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
cite \cite{bake67, Acme72, cake71, Delta71}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{junk}
\end{document}
```

I get the following result, sorted by year and, within a year, by surname:

[image]

If you wish the reverse order (chronologically descending), then the line near the end of the `apalike.bst` file that reads

```
ITERATE {call.type$}
```

must be changed to

```
REVERSE {call.type$}
```

Of course, this means that, within a given year, surnames will likewise be sorted in reverse order, too (alphabetically backwards).

---

When using the original definition, which was

```
%                               Now that the label is right we sort for real,
%                               on sort.label then year then title.  This is
%                               for the second sorting pass.
FUNCTION {bib.sort.order}
{ sort.label
  "    "
  *
  year field.or.null sortify
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}
```

the result is sorted by surname as

[image]