# Sort by order of bibtex entries in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I am using biblatex for my academic CV as follows:

```
\usepackage[sorting=debug,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\bibliography{../bibs/publications}

...

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
```

As you can tell, I am using the `sort=debug` option in to control which order the biblatex entries get printed. However, this requires that I pick my key names in `../bibs/publications.bib` to reflect the desired order; e.g.:

```
 @article {1_somearticle,
   ...
 }

 @article {2_somearticle,
   ...
 }
```

Obviously, this is rather tedious to update when I want to add a new work. Is there a way to get biblatex to print the bibliography entries in the order they are listed in the bibtex file?

Comment: `sorting=none` and `\nocite{somekey,otherkey,differentkey}` should I think print in order of the appearance in `\nocite`.  Would I think be easier to update.  Or could you just sort the bibliography by year?  Maybe [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4466/106162).

Comment: The idea is that `biblatex` does the sorting for you - always. Is there any sense to the ordering in the `.bib` file? It would be no trouble sorting by full date, ... I'm assuming here that the ordering in the CV is not supposed to be random.

Comment: @DaiBowen: this produces empty output

Comment: @moewe: multiple papers per year dictates that I would like to put the most recent one at the top; I'm also not a huge fan of putting in more detailed information beyond year.

Comment: Well, you can of course add manual information like `sortyear` to have more fine-grained control over the sorting "within" one year. Needless to say that even if you give the full date (why would you not be a fan?) there is no need that the output show the full year.

Comment: What exactly is the "algorithm" by which you want to sort? If it isn't to far off anything normal, I'm sure it can be implemented in `biblatex` without too much work (if your `.bib` file gives the needed information that is, but that should not be too hard to manage - manually ordering the `.bib` file sounds worse).

Comment: @moewe: I guess I wouldn't want to go through the extra work of putting in additional date details every time I add to the bibtex. It could be dummy data, but then my OCD/pedantry kicks in (i.e., I'd prefer a cleaner solution). Ideally I would like to manually order the ```.bib``` file)

Comment: Well, I wouldn't be trying to steer you to another solution if sorting "by `.bib` file" was possible. As far as I know it isn't. Of course you can try and write a script that numbers your references in the `.bib` correctly (I couldn't, but it should be possible). You can of course also ask the Biber maintainer to include that feature - it probably wouldn't be very high up the list, but if it easy enough (not exactly sure), he might go for it.  ...

Comment: ... Frankly though, I believe adding the full date, that is writing `date = {2016-07-08}` instead of `year = {2016}`, is less awkward than manually sorting things in the `.bib`. And only marginally more work.

Comment: @moewe: thanks! Perhaps I will just do that.

Comment: If you have found an answer that works for you, please do not hesitate to post a self-answer in case others have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of entries in the `.bib` file is currently not something Biber can sort by. The information could probably be accessed easily, but there is no interface for it right now.

In a way sorting by order of entries in the `.bib` goes against the spirit of Biber/BibTeX. The idea is that the backend sorts your bibliography by some meaningful algorithm (cite order, values of fields, ...) instead of relying on you to sort the `.bib` file.

In your case where you want to sort by year and have multiple works from the same year you can either use the `sortyear` field to control the order (`sortyear = {2016-1}`, `sortyear = {2016-2}`) or you give more detailed publication dates `date = {2016-04-23}` and sort by full date (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46868/35864) - you don't even have to print the full date in the document).

I don't believe that the two options of the last paragraph are significantly more work than sorting the references manually in the `.bib` by moving them around.