# Sort bibliography by date with BibTeX

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, sorting, bibliographystyle

Is it possible to make BibTeX sort bibliography entries by date? The best I have found to date is to add a `\nocite` command at the top of my document listing all citations in the order I want them. This works when the bibliography is small, but becomes tedious very fast. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\nocite{li_2020}\nocite{schmidt_2018}\nocite{ribeiro_2017}

Ratione dolores totam magnam fugit commodi \cite{ribeiro_2017}. 
Aliquam commodi voluptatibus culpa voluptatem sed odio. 
Ut ipsum et ipsam non \cite{li_2020}. 
Deserunt laudantium non nihil fuga possimus suscipit \cite{schmidt_2018}. 
Omnis similique et tempora quaerat occaecati sint mollitia.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use a `\bibliographystyle` that sorts in reverse chronological order, see for example http://www.math.cmu.edu/~gautam/sj/blog/20150324-bibtex-reverse.html or https://github.com/plessl/latex-goodies/tree/master/bibstyles/plainyr-rev. The last one is from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4461/how-to-sort-bibtex-references-in-reverse-chronological-order, I'll vote to close as a duplicate.